# What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems they canceled in Python 3 all the easy ways to quickly load a script by removing `execfile()`.

Is there an obvious alternative I'm missing?

Comment: `reload` is back, as [`imp.reload`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload), since 3.2.

Comment: If you are using Python interactively consider using IPython:
```%run script_name``` works with all version of Python.

Comment: Since 3.4 `imp` is `importlib`  (which must be imported): `importlib.reload(mod_name)` imports and executes `mod_name`.

Comment: what's wrong with runfile("filename.py") ?

Comment: Thanks @mousomer!! I was precisely looking for the functionality of `runfile()` since I needed to run a Python script that executes in its own namespace (as opposed to executing on the _calling_ namespace).
My application: add the directory of the called script to the system path (`sys.path`) using the `__file__` attribute: if we use `execfile()` or its equivalent in Python 3 (`exec(open('file.py').read())`) the included script is run in the calling namespace and thus `__file__` resolves to the _calling_ file name.

Comment: @TarmoPikaro rolled back your edits, modifying `sys.argv` is really outside the scope of this function and has some (IMHO) unacceptable down-sides since the caller might be using sys.argv elsewhere. It's possible this could be temporarily overridden (which isn't thread-safe)... but might still be acceptable in some cases. Whatever the case - this wasn't supported by the original execfile, if you want to optionally pass environment, argv, working directory ... etc. This could be a separate answer.

Answer (score 492, accepted):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=execfile#builtins), instead of

```
execfile("./filename")
```

Use

```
exec(open("./filename").read())
```

See:

- [What’s New In Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.3/whatsnew/3.0.html?highlight=execfile#builtins)
- [`execfile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#execfile)
- [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec)

Comment: Any idea why they would do such a thing? This is so much more verbose than before. Also, it doesn't work for me on Python3.3. I get "No such file or directory" when I exec(open('./some_file').read()). I have tried including the '.py' extension and also excluding the './' as well

Comment: Simple and it works as intended for text file. You can even get the output by adding a comma before the last bracket and the name of the output variable.

Comment: Less trivially, this doesn't provide line numbers when exceptions are raised, as did execfile().

Comment: You'll need to `close` that file handle too. Another reason to dislike the change from python 2.

Comment: How do you reload imported modules within `filename` ? Without having to exit and re-enter the python environment

Comment: @Rebs you don't need to close the file handle in that example, it will be done automatically (at least in regular CPython)

Comment: @tiho How so? A call to `open` always needs a follow up call to `close` https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: @Rebs in CPython objects are garbage-collected as soon as their reference count goes to 0, only circular references may delay this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449489/when-are-objects-garbage-collected-in-python). In that case that should happen right after read() returns. And file objects are closed on deletion (NB: I realize this link explicitly says "always close files", which is indeed good practice to follow in general)

Comment: @tiho Interesting, I was under the impression the object wasn't smart enough to close itself. Thanks for opening my eyes to this. I think its still good practice to put a `close` along side an `open` call (or better yet use the `with` statement), you never know how long a variable will linger for, where the code will be used from, nor where the code will end up being pasted.

Comment: @Rebs i always use `with` because im a forgetful person and 99% of the time forget to close the file, using `with` eliminates this issue :)

Comment: how can I pass arguments to this "exec(open("./filename").read())" command ? For example I have a file with data called input_data.csv and want to pass it to script, thanks

Comment: Some weird edge cases involving executing a file that updates already defined functions and classes can be fixed by including `globals()` as the second argument for `exec`

Comment: `with open('./filename') as f: exec(f.read())`  deals with opening and closing the file

Comment: @JonathanHartley  The question "why do such a thing" remains unanswered. These things do add up.

Comment: What does the `./` do?  In other words, what is the difference (if any) between `open("./filename")` and `open("filename")`?

Comment: @mpb: Nothing: some people don’t understand `PATH` and think the `./` means “(user-written) program”.

Comment: __file__ isn't reset, so if ./filename depends on using that in its logic, e.g. for activating a virtual environment, this won't work.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/41658338/124042 is better

Answer (score 246):

You are just supposed to read the file and exec the code yourself. 2to3 current replaces

```
execfile("somefile.py", global_vars, local_vars)
```

as

```
with open("somefile.py") as f:
    code = compile(f.read(), "somefile.py", 'exec')
    exec(code, global_vars, local_vars)
```

(The compile call isn't strictly needed, but it associates the filename with the code object making debugging a little easier.)

See:

- http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/functions.html#execfile
- http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.3/library/functions.html#compile
- http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: This works for me. However, I noticed that you've written the local and global arguments in the wrong order. It's actually: exec(object[, globals[, locals]]). Of course if you had the arguments flipped in the original, then 2to3 will produce exactly what you said. :)

Comment: Was pleased to discover that, if you can omit global_vars and local_vars, the python3 replacement here works under python2 as well. Even though `exec` is a statement in python2, `exec(code)` works because the parens just get ignored.

Comment: +1 for using compile. My `"somefile.py"` contained `inspect.getsourcefile(lambda _: None)` which was failing without the compile, because the `inspect` module couldn't determine where the code was coming from.

Comment: That's... really ugly. Any idea why they got rid of execfile() in 3.x? execfile also made it easy to pass commandline args.

Comment: `open("somefile.py")` may be incorrect if `somefile.py` uses a character encoding different from `locale.getpreferredencoding()`. `tokenize.open()` could be used instead.

Comment: Another caveat: in python 2, `compile()` will fail if the source code has trailing whitespace or uses line endings other than '\n'.

Answer (score 101):

While `exec(open("filename").read())` is often given as an alternative to `execfile("filename")`, it misses important details that `execfile` supported.

The following function for Python3.x is as close as I could get to having the same behavior as executing a file directly. That matches running `python /path/to/somefile.py`.

```py
def execfile(filepath, globals=None, locals=None):
    if globals is None:
        globals = {}
    globals.update({
        "__file__": filepath,
        "__name__": "__main__",
    })
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        exec(compile(file.read(), filepath, 'exec'), globals, locals)

# Execute the file.
execfile("/path/to/somefile.py")
```

**Notes:**

- Uses binary file reading to avoid encoding issues.
- Guaranteed to close the file *(Python3.x warns about this).*
- Defines `__main__`, some scripts depend on this to check if they are loading as a module or not for eg. `if __name__ == "__main__"`.
- Setting `__file__` is nicer for exception messages and some scripts use `__file__` to get the paths of other files relative to them.
- Takes optional globals & locals arguments, modifying them in-place as `execfile` does - so you can access any variables defined by reading back the variables after running.
- Unlike Python2's `execfile` this does **not** modify the current namespace by default. For that you have to explicitly pass in `globals()` & `locals()`.

Answer (score 81):

As [suggested on the python-dev](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-June/134992.html) mailinglist recently, the [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html) module might be a viable alternative. Quoting from that message:

> https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_path
>
> ```
> import runpy
> file_globals = runpy.run_path("file.py")
> ```

There are subtle differences to `execfile`:

- `run_path` always creates a new namespace. It executes the code as a module, so there is no difference between globals and locals (which is why there is only a `init_globals` argument). The globals are returned.

  `execfile` executed in the current namespace or the given namespace. The semantics of `locals` and `globals`, if given, were similar to locals and globals inside a class definition.
- `run_path` can not only execute files, but also eggs and directories (refer to its documentation for details).

Comment: For some reason, it outputs to the screen a lot of information it was not asked to print ('__builtins__' etc in Anaconda Python 3). Is there some way to turn this off so that only the information which I output with print() gets visualized?

Comment: Is it also possible to get all the variables in the current workspace instead of them all being stored in `file_globals`? This would save having to type the `file_globals['...']` for every variable.

Comment: "Furthermore, any functions and classes defined by the executed code are not guaranteed to work correctly after a runpy function has returned." Worth noting, depending on your use-case

Comment: @Adriaan Execute "globals().update(file_globals)". Personally I like this solution best because I can possibly catch errors before deciding to update the current workspace.

Comment: @nodakai Thanks for the info, I missed that. Never had any problem like that yet, I wonder what is likely to set that off.

Answer (score 27):

This one is better, since it takes the globals and locals from the caller:

```
import sys
def execfile(filename, globals=None, locals=None):
    if globals is None:
        globals = sys._getframe(1).f_globals
    if locals is None:
        locals = sys._getframe(1).f_locals
    with open(filename, "r") as fh:
        exec(fh.read()+"\n", globals, locals)
```

Comment: Actually, this one is the closer to py2 `execfile`. It even worked for my when using pytests where other solutions posted above failed. Thx! :)

Answer (score 17):

You could write your own function:

```
def xfile(afile, globalz=None, localz=None):
    with open(afile, "r") as fh:
        exec(fh.read(), globalz, localz)
```

If you really needed to...

Comment: -1: the exec statment doesn't work this way. Code doesn't run in any version of python.

Comment: -1: The default parameter values are evaluated at function definition time, making both `globals` and `locals` point to the global namespace fo the module containing the definition of `execfile()` rather than to the global and local namespace of the caller.  The correct approach is to use `None` as default value and determine the caller's globals and locals via the introspection capabilities of the `inspect` module.

Answer (score 15):

If the script you want to load is in the same directory than the one you run, maybe "import" will do the job ?

If you need to dynamically import code the built-in function [__ import__](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) and the module [imp](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html) are worth looking at.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path = ['/path/to/script'] + sys.path
>>> __import__('test')
<module 'test' from '/path/to/script/test.pyc'>
>>> __import__('test').run()
'Hello world!'
```

test.py:

```
def run():
        return "Hello world!"
```

If you're using Python 3.1 or later, you should also take a look at [importlib](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/library/importlib.html).

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. This blog does a good job explaining `importlib` https://dev.to/0xcrypto/dynamic-importing-stuff-in-python--1805

Comment: This link is dead as I deleted my dev.to account. Reposted at https://hackberry.xyz/dynamic-importing-stuff-in-python

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I had (`file` is already assigned to the path to the file with the source code in both examples):

```
execfile(file)
```

Here's what I replaced it with:

```
exec(compile(open(file).read(), file, 'exec'))
```

My favorite part: the second version works just fine in both Python 2 and 3, meaning it's not necessary to add in version dependent logic.

Answer (score 8):

Avoid `exec()` if you can. For most applications, it's cleaner to make use of Python's import system.

This function uses built-in [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to execute a file as an actual module:

```
from importlib import util

def load_file_as_module(name, location):
    spec = util.spec_from_file_location(name, location)
    module = util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

### Usage example

Let's have a file `foo.py`:

```
def hello():
    return 'hi from module!'
print('imported from', __file__, 'as', __name__)
```

And import it as a regular module:

```
>>> mod = load_file_as_module('mymodule', './foo.py')
imported from /tmp/foo.py as mymodule
>>> mod.hello()
hi from module!
>>> type(mod)
<class 'module'>
```

### Advantages

This approach doesn't pollute namespaces or messes with your `$PATH` whereas `exec()` runs code directly in the context of the current function, potentially causing name collisions. Also, module attributes like `__file__` and `__name__` will be set correctly, and code locations are preserved. So, if you've attached a debugger or if the module raises an exception, you will get usable tracebacks.

Note that one minor difference from static imports is that the module gets imported (executed) every time you run `load_file_as_module()`, and not just once as with the `import` keyword.

Comment: Great answer!  You could extend it by illustrating how calling `load_file` twice for the same file will or will not reload the file (I wouldn't know without trying).

Comment: @gerrit Thanks! I added a note. (It's (re-)executed on every call as the name of `loader.exec_module()` somewhat suggests.)

Answer (score 6):

Note that the above pattern will fail if you're using PEP-263 encoding declarations
that aren't ascii or utf-8. You need to find the encoding of the data, and encode it 
correctly before handing it to exec().

```
class python3Execfile(object):
    def _get_file_encoding(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'rb') as fp:
            try:
                return tokenize.detect_encoding(fp.readline)[0]
            except SyntaxError:
                return "utf-8"

    def my_execfile(filename):
        globals['__file__'] = filename
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding=self._get_file_encoding(filename)) as fp:
            contents = fp.read()
        if not contents.endswith("\n"):
            # http://bugs.python.org/issue10204
            contents += "\n"
        exec(contents, globals, globals)
```

Comment: What is "the above pattern"? Please use links when referring to other posts on StackOverflow. Relative positioning terms like "the above" don't work, as there are 3 different ways of sorting answers (by votes, by date, or by activity) and the most common one (by votes) is volatile. Over time your post and posts around yours will end up with different scores, meaning they'll be rearranged and such comparisons will be less useful.

Comment: Very good point. And given that I wrote this answer almost six months ago, I assume by "above pattern" I meant https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849077/165082 (which unfortunately you have to click on to resolve), or better still Noam's answer:

Comment: Generally when I want to refer to other answers to the same question from my answer, I type "Noam's Answer" (for example) and link the text to the answer I'm referring to, just for in case the answer becomes disassociated from the user in the future, IE, because the user changes their account name or the post becomes a communal wiki because too many edits have been made on it.

Comment: How do you get the URL to a specific "answer" with in a post, excluding the poster's name of the answer?

Comment: View the source and get the ID.  For example, your question would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0/5643233?noredirect=1#comment47190856_5643233#comment-47190856 .

I'm all for a better method, but don't see anything when I hover near the comment

Comment: Related: [Read a unicode file in python which declares its encoding in the same way as python source](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6078902/95735)

Comment: @Eric [Comment Reply Attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0#comment-47200996) Not related to answer; just trying out commenting trick mentioned by Eric. Also In Google Chrome right-click-Inspect Element helps find the comment ID.

Comment: @Eric: to get a link to an answer: click `share` link under it. To get a link to a comment, right-click on the timestamp and click "copy link address".

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Noted.

Answer (score 4):

Also, while not a pure Python solution, if you're using IPython (as you probably should anyway), you can do:

```
%run /path/to/filename.py
```

Which is equally easy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just a newbie here so maybe it's pure luck if I found this :

After trying to run a script from the interpreter prompt >>> with the command

```
    execfile('filename.py')
```

for which I got a "NameError: name 'execfile' is not defined" I tried a very basic

```
    import filename
```

it worked well :-)

I hope this can be helpful and thank you all for the great hints, examples and all those masterly commented pieces of code that are a great inspiration for newcomers !

I use Ubuntu 16.014 LTS x64.  *Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux*