# How to execute a file within the Python interpreter?

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a file with Python commands from within the interpreter.

I'm trying to use variables and settings from that file, not to invoke a separate process.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

Several ways.

- From the shell

  ```
  python someFile.py
  ```
- From inside IDLE, hit **F5**.
- If you're typing interactively, try this (**Python3**):

  ```
  >>> exec(open("filename.py").read())
  ```
- For Python 2:

  ```
  >>> variables= {}
  >>> execfile( "someFile.py", variables )
  >>> print variables # globals from the someFile module
  ```

Comment: is there any way to provide `stdin` from a file like using `<` to the executing script with in the `execfile()`.? @s-lott

Comment: @pzkpfw python can point to any version of python. I have seen environments with *only* python v3 where `python` points to `python3`.

Comment: @pzkpfw That depends on what `python` executable the system finds when looking through the folders in the environment variable `PATH`.

Comment: For random GIS people I could call this in ArcGIS Pro 
exec(open("D:\\Scripts\\myscript.py").read())

Comment: I'm finding that the F5 bullet applies to Spyder specifically, and it runs the already-opened temp.py.  If I just run `python` at the Conda prompt, F5 doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 276):

**For Python 2:**

```
>>> execfile('filename.py')
```

**For Python 3:**

```
>>> exec(open("filename.py").read())
# or
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> exec(Path("filename.py").read_text())
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile). If you are using Python 3.0, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3-0).

See answer by @S.Lott for an example of how you access globals from filename.py after executing it.

Comment: What does read method do? Unfortunately the official documentation site doesn't provide a clear example and explanation.

Comment: It reads the file and returns (by default) the entire contents in one single string, see e.g. [w3schools page on file open](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_open.asp).

Comment: Here are the docs for open(): https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html

Answer (score 114):

### Python 2 + Python 3

```
exec(open("./path/to/script.py").read(), globals())
```

This will execute a script and put all it's global variables in the interpreter's global scope (the normal behavior in most scripting environments).

[Python 3 `exec` Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

Comment: Is there a way to pass a parameter to the script?  the following doesn't work:   exec(open"setup.py  install").read(), globals())

Comment: @ben that won't work because `open` directly reads the code from the script. To pass arguments, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675453/5888301), but instead of `execfile`, obviously use `exec` and `open` as shown above.

Answer (score 85):

Surprised I haven't seen this yet. You can execute a file and then leave the interpreter open after execution terminates using the `-i` option:

```
| foo.py |
----------
testvar = 10

def bar(bing):
  return bing*3

--------



$ python -i foo.py
>>> testvar 
10
>>> bar(6)
18
```

Answer (score 32):

> I'm trying to use variables and settings from that file, not to invoke a separate process.

Well, simply importing the file with `import filename` (minus .py, needs to be in the same directory or on your `PYTHONPATH`) will run the file, making its variables, functions, classes, etc. available in the `filename.variable` namespace.

So if you have `cheddar.py` with the variable spam and the function eggs – you can import them with `import cheddar`, access the variable with `cheddar.spam` and run the function by calling `cheddar.eggs()`

If you have code in `cheddar.py` that is outside a function, it will be run immediately, but building applications that runs stuff on import is going to make it hard to reuse your code. If a all possible, put everything inside functions or classes.

Comment: That won't use the global namespace, as the question requires. Use instead `from filename import *`

Comment: The question does not specifically mention using a global namespace, that may be what the OP wants, but it is not obvious from the question.

Answer (score 19):

From my view, the best way is:

```
import yourfile
```

and after modifying yourfile.py

```
reload(yourfile)
```

or  in python3:

```
import imp; 
imp.reload(yourfile)
```

but this will make the function and classes looks like that:
yourfile.function1, yourfile.class1.....

If you cannot accept those,
the finally solution is:

```
reload(yourfile)
from yourfile import *
```

Comment: yep... this seems to be the best way... THX!     but...       reload isn't working for me...        i'm in Python 3.9.5...           any ideas???

Comment: @ZEE , I'm using python 3.8.5, I can use: `from importlib import reload`. It looks like the `imp` has been merged to the `importlib`

Answer (score 12):

Just do,

```
from my_file import *
```

Make sure not to add .py extension. If your .py file in subdirectory use,

```
from my_dir.my_file import *
```

Answer (score 9):

**For Python 3:**

```
>>> exec(open("helloworld.py").read())
```

Make sure that you're in the correct directory before running the command.

To run a file from a different directory, you can use the below command:

```
with open ("C:\\Users\\UserName\\SomeFolder\\helloworld.py", "r") as file:
    exec(file.read())
```

Answer (score 8):

I am not an expert but this is what I noticed:

if your code is mycode.py for instance, and you type just 'import mycode', Python will execute it but it will not make all your variables available to the interpreter.  I found that you should type actually 'from mycode import *' if you want to make all variables available to the interpreter.

Comment: Plus, it should be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 8):

For python3 use either with `xxxx = name` of `yourfile`.

```
exec(open('./xxxx.py').read())
```

Answer (score 5):

Supposing you desire the following features:

1. Source file behaves properly in your debugger (filename shows in stack, etc)
2. `__name__ == '__main__'` is True so scripts behave properly as scripts.

The `exec(open('foo.py').read())` fails feature 1
The `import foo` strategy fails feature 2

To get both, you need this:

```py
    source = open(filename).read()
    code = compile(source, filename, 'exec')
    exec(code)
```

Comment: An alternative is to use `runpy.run_path`. Source: [python - File "<string>" traceback with line preview - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63403013/5267751) -- but that one will create a separate "module" for the new script, the old `globals()` dict passed in (if any) will remain unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

```
python -c "exec(open('main.py').read())"
```