# Execute a file with arguments in Python shell

Tags: python, shell

I would like to run a command in Python Shell to execute a file with an argument.

For example: `execfile("abc.py")` but how to add 2 arguments?

Comment: How is the code in the file you want to execute retrieve the arguments?

Comment: I know this is old question, but you could alternately probably pass values to run a py file in a file and just open it up and read in the values.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`execfile` runs a Python file, but by loading it, not as a script. You can only pass in variable bindings, not arguments.

If you want to run a program from within Python, use [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). E.g.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['./abc.py', arg1, arg2])
```

Comment: The following format works for me: `subprocess.call("python abc.py 'arg1'", shell=True)`

Comment: @geotheory Sure that works, but it's less safe and it gets hairy when you want to pass strings with quotes in them to a subprocess.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean with "loading it,  not as a script"? What's the difference?

Comment: @marco: The idea is that a “script” would be a separate process with its own command line.  `execfile` runs in the current process, so (if it’s relevant) uses the *current* command line.  In that sense, you can’t use it *without* “passing” arguments!

Answer (score 60):

Actually, wouldn't we want to do this?

```
import sys
sys.argv = ['abc.py','arg1', 'arg2']
execfile('abc.py')
```

Comment: ...and then, it turns out, that `python` points to a different (2-vs-3) version of Python :)

Comment: I have to downvote buggywhip's answer because he missed this subtlety.

Comment: Even still this will fail if `abc.py` reads `from sys import argv`

Answer (score 59):

try this:

```
import sys
sys.argv = ['arg1', 'arg2']
execfile('abc.py')
```

Note that when `abc.py` finishes, control will be returned to the calling program.  Note too that `abc.py` can call `quit()` if indeed finished.

Comment: Nothing is being passed to `abc.py` as far as I can tell, nor can I see why it should.

Comment: When my 'abc.py' has `argparse` to parse input arguments, I got an error with this method: too few arguments. I ran `python abc.py arg1 arg2` in terminal (this method works without an error) and then printed the content of `sys.argv` by printing and found that `sys.argv` contains the name `'abc.py'` as the first element of the list. Actually, **user2757262's code below** with `sys.argv = ['abc.py','arg1', 'arg2']` was the one that worked!

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html#sys.argv) also says, "`argv[0]` is the script name" .

Comment: @AntiEarth: There being but one `sys` in a process, it will find what you put there.

Comment: @KouichiC.Nakamura I see that ```execfile``` is removed from Python3. How can I use ```exec``` with arguments?

Answer (score 30):

```
import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'abc.py', 'argument1', 'argument2'])
```

Answer (score 12):

You're confusing loading a module into the current interpreter process and calling a Python script externally.

The former can be done by `import`ing the file you're interested in. [execfile](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) is similar to importing but it simply evaluates the file rather than creates a module out of it. Similar to "sourcing" in a shell script.

The latter can be done using the subprocess module. You spawn off another instance of the interpreter and pass whatever parameters you want to that. This is similar to shelling out in a shell script using backticks.

Answer (score 12):

For more interesting scenarios, you could also look at the `runpy` module. Since python 2.7, it has the `run_path` function. E.g:

```
import runpy
import sys

# argv[0] will be replaced by runpy
# You could also skip this if you get sys.argv populated
# via other means
sys.argv = ['', 'arg1' 'arg2']
runpy.run_path('./abc.py', run_name='__main__')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't pass command line arguments with `execfile()`. Look at [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Comment: See @user2757262's answer above.

Answer (score 2):

If you set `PYTHONINSPECT` in the python file you want to execute

[repl.py]

```
import os
import sys
from time import time 
os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = 'True'
t=time()
argv=sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)]
```

there is no need to use `execfile`, and you can directly run the file with arguments as usual in the shell:

```
python repl.py one two 3
>>> t
1513989378.880822
>>> argv
['one', 'two', '3']
```

Comment: This goes without saying for some users, but you can use the above approach on variables that were defined/used within functions by adding those variables to the global namespace inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run the scripts in parallel and give them different arguments you can do like below.

```
import os
os.system("python script.py arg1 arg2 & python script.py arg11 arg22")
```

Comment: Please don’t recommend `os.system`—its legitimate use cases are *very* rare.

Comment: Why is it illegitimate @DavisHerring? This comment isn't helpful to future readers who may want to know why Mehmet's solution is unsuitable.

Comment: @Lou: That doesn't fit in a comment.  I was surprised that I couldn't find one to link here, so I [asked/answered my own](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64329284/8586227).

Answer (score 1):

Besides `subprocess.call`, you can also use `subprocess.Popen`. Like the following

`subprocess.Popen(['./script', arg1, arg2])`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
subprocess.call("python abc.py arg1 arg2", shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runfile('abc.py', ['arg1', 'arg2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python.exe', './abc.py', arg1, arg2])
```