# TypeError: must be dict, not str

Tags: python

Hey guys I was trying to use the argument variable in Python however am unable to execute the program at the terminal.

**Program:**

```
from sys import argv

script,first,second,third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second 
print "Your third variable is:", third
```

**Output:**

```
>>> execfile("lesson13.py","dog","cat")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be dict, not str
>>>
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the program, you just misuse `execfile`.

Answer (score 4):

[`execfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#execfile) doesn't take command arguments. Try using [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) instead.

Comment: Here is a SE question for the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788891/execfile-with-argument-in-python-shell

Comment: >>> subprocess.call('lesson13.py','kill','bill','kim')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'subprocess' is not defined

Comment: `subprocess is not defined` Did you import it?  Update your post if you still can't resolve!