# TypeError: super(type, obj) when running pyprocessing script interactively

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyprocessing

Python 2.7.3:

Create the simplest possible [`pyprocessing`](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/) file and save it as `foo.py`:

```
from pyprocessing import *

def setup():
    size(100,100)

def draw():
    rect(10,10,10,10)

run()
```

Now in python:

```
>>> execfile('foo.py')
```

The file runs as expected. Close the `pyprocessing` window to return to the prompt and type:

```
>>> execfile('foo.py')
```

and you're greeted with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 9, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyprocessing-0.1.3.22-py2.7.egg/pyprocessing/__init__.py", line 417, in run
    __main__.setup()
  File "foo.py", line 4, in setup
    size(100,100)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyprocessing-0.1.3.22-py2.7.egg/pyprocessing/__init__.py", line 335, in size
    config=canvas.config, caption=caption, visible = isVisible)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyprocessing-0.1.3.22-py2.7.egg/pyprocessing/flippolicy.py", line 142, in __init__
    super(BackupWindow, self).__init__(*args, **keyargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 474, in __init__
    super(XlibWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 690, in __init__
    self.set_visible(True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 878, in set_visible
    self._map()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/xlib/__init__.py", line 710, in _map
    self.dispatch_event('on_resize', self._width, self._height)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 1219, in dispatch_event
    EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/event.py", line 352, in dispatch_event
    event_type, args, getattr(self, event_type))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyglet-1.1.4-py2.7.egg/pyglet/event.py", line 349, in dispatch_event
    return getattr(self, event_type)(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyprocessing-0.1.3.22-py2.7.egg/pyprocessing/flippolicy.py", line 168, in on_resize
    super (FBOWindow, self).on_resize(w,h)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

What is happening here? Is this a bug are am I using `pyprocessing` wrong?

Comment: hi, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788891/execfile-with-argument-in-python-shell

Comment: @archetipo: could you explain how that's relevant to this question?

Comment: because is not a good way to running this type of script , if you try to run this script with subprocess , you receive the same error? for definition pyprocessing is built upon openGL and pyglet ,and this require a dedicated process to make it stable.

Comment: `call([sys.executable, 'foo.py'])` works fine. Do you want to write this up as a solution, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) spawns a separate process each time:

```
from subprocess import call 
call([sys.executable, 'foo.py'])
```

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196074/starting-a-background-process-in-python) for a fuller discussion of `subprocess.call`.

Comment: read the comments, my up vote is not a thank you, but a good, because the solution was reasoned together ... in this question, the solution is the approach not the method used ..