# pyprocessing doesn't quit on Windows

Tags: python, processing, pyprocessing

Here is a quote from the [pyprocessing Usage Instructions wiki](http://code.google.com/p/pyprocessing/wiki/UsageInstructions):

> In principle, run() does not return, but you can terminate the application by typing the ESC key.

If I start pyprocessing interactively (not using `subprocess.call` as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155140/typeerror-supertype-obj-when-running-pyprocessing-script-interactively)), the Escape key does nothing to stop the process:

```
>>> from pyprocessing import *
>>> # At this point, nothing will close the pyprocessing window except a force-quit
... # making debugging a pyprocessing app pretty hard
```

Is there a way to kill the pyprocessing process once it's started from an interactive python shell?

Comment: p.s. there's no `pyprocessing` tag and I don't have the rep to create one!

Comment: Added the tag and retagged relevant questions I could find

Comment: @LondonRob Not quite the solution you're looking for, but how about trying the new Python mode in Processing 2.1.2 ? I've used in on Windows 8 and it seems to work fine

Comment: @LondonRob No worries, say hi to Martin Austwick for me ;)