# python line profiler view result

Tags: python, profiler

I have ran `kernprof` on a file called `RP.py` and it spits out `RP.py.lprof`

Now, i'm trying to view this file. If i open a `cmd` window and type 
`python -m line_profiler RP.py.lprof` it gives me the text, but it not formatted in a way that I can read it.

Is there a way to 1) turn `lprof` into text?

or run it in a shell. I have tried:

```
import sys
import subprocess
subprocess.call([sys.executable,'C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-m', 'line_profiler', 'RP.py.lprof'])
```

[Execute a file with arguments in Python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788891/execfile-with-argument-in-python-shell) from this link. But this doesn't work.

Comment: I don't have ready access to a Windows box, but my first guess based on the description is that the line-endings are \n instead of \r\n. Try piping the results to a text file and then open it in a programmer's editor (not Notepad). `python -m line_profiler RP.py.lprof > results.txt`

Comment: worked. if you put it in an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with kernprof, so I almost didn't say anything, but glad you got a usable result. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't have ready access to a Windows box, but my first guess based on the description is that the line-endings are `\n` instead of `\r\n`. Try piping the results to a text file and then open it in a programmer's editor (*not* Notepad).

`python -m line_profiler RP.py.lprof > results.txt`

Comment: Note that there might also be a solution to this that is more idiomatic to a Windows user, which I might not be aware of. This is just the 10lb. sledge I break out when line-endings are goofed up.