# wxPython: make variables available to an imported class?

Tags: python, class, wxpython

I have written a wxPython GUI which assigns some variables upon a button click.

```
def OnGo(self, event):
    inputdatadirectory = self.txtbx1.GetValue() 
    outputsavedirectory = self.txtbx2.GetValue()
    mcadata = self.txtbx3.GetValue()
    current_dir = os.getcwd()
    execfile(current_dir+"\\aEDXD.py")
```

I then run execfile, and the executed file imports and runs a class from another file.

How can I make the variables I've defined through my GUI available to the imported class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788891/execfile-with-argument-in-python-shell

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, although it will probably be difficult to debug. Here is a silly example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Go")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onGo)
        self.Show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onGo(self, event):
        """"""
        foobar = "This is a test!"
        execfile("foo.py")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

And here is the **foo.py** file.

```
print foobar
```

If you run the wxPython script, it will execute **foo.py** which has access to the locals and globals in the wxPython script. You won't be able to run foo.py by itself though. See the following:

- [Execute a file with arguments in Python shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788891/execfile-with-argument-in-python-shell)
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile

Comment: But what if foo.py imports a class from another module. Will that class have access to the variables?

Comment: If foo imports another class, it would have to pass those variables to that class.