# Execute .py script from sikuli passing arguments

Tags: python, numpy, jython, sikuli

I have a code to be executed in Sikuli, and I want to call an external Python Script to analyze the data from a generated file.

I have tried directly ***importing*** the .py file, ***subprocess.call(),*** ***subprocess.Popen()*** and ***execfile()***

I have two main problems:

- Firstly, I need to pass some arguments to the python script (specifically the path of the file to analyze [str] and the test number [int]).
- Secondly, my .py script uses libraries such as **matplotlib.pyplot** or **numpy** that cannot be executed by Jython.

I am lost already, after trying all the possibilities I could think of. What should work best? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to a Sikuli script as easy as that:

```
C:\Sikulix\runScript.cmd -r Tests\Test.sikuli --arg argVal
```

then you can access it like this:

```
print sys.argv[1]
```

where `1` is the order of an argument as they appear in command line.

You can use `execfile` like this:

```
execfile("C:\SikuliX\Tests\Test.py")
```

the issue with this however is that `execfile` runs a Python file [by loading it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5788946/1119381) and not as a script. You can only pass in variable bindings, not arguments.

If you want to run a program from within Python, use subprocess.call. E.g.

```
subprocess.call(['./abc.py', arg1, arg2])
```