# Python Shell running file.py with argument

Tags: python, paraview

I am using Paraview's Python Shell and need to run a script with parameters. I've already tried to run a script without parameters using: `exec(open('/home/otamichalek/Documents/Scritps/V1/OpenFile-V1-sample.py').read())`

then I created V2 of the script, which instead of exact definition of filename has `filename = str(sys.argv[1])`

I need to input multiple arguments, but I wanted to try it using just one first. I need something like `exec(open('/home/otamichalek/Documents/Scritps/V1/OpenFile-V1-sample.py' **'FileToOpenWithData'**).read())`

Appreciate any help

Comment: Why are you using exec to open a file?

Comment: Simple open did not work for me. Should I use something else?

Comment: Now I have tried ```import sys``` then ```sys.argv=['data file']``` and then ```execfile(/home/otamichalek/Documents/Scritps/OpenFile-V2-short.py)``` and I am getting 

``` Traceback (most recent call last):```
 ``` File "/usr/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode```
```    exec(code, self.locals)```
```  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>```
```TypeError: 'str' object is not callable```

Comment: If you dont really need the GUI, you can use pvpython / pvbatch to run ParaView Script. Otherwise, I think you'd better create a module with a method taking a file list as arguments

Comment: I needed the GUI to check that it does what I want it to. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work:

```
import runpy, sys

#argv[0] will be replaced by runpy

sys.argv = ['', 'datafile']
runpy.run_path('script.py')
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259769/13840062