# Python: how do I read (not run) a shell script, inserting arguments along the way

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I have a simple shell script `script.sh`:

```
echo "ubuntu:$1" | sudo chpasswd
```

I need to open the script, read it, insert the argument, and save it as a string like so: `'echo "ubuntu:arg_passed_when_opening" | sudo chpasswd'` using Python.

All the options suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788891/execute-a-file-with-arguments-in-python-shell) actually execute the script, which is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a job for regex. Open the file, do `re.sub("$1", arg, file_contents)`, and you're done.

Comment: Why a regex? It's a simple string replace.

Comment: Yeah, that'd work too

Comment: The shell script is a file, and you can open it as a file and read/write whatever you want. (PS: It really sounds like you've misunderstood the task here)

Comment: Why are you opening and modifying a shell script, versus calling it with an argument? This is an unusual and error prone request. Could it be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Perhaps you could tell us why you're doing it and what the underlying problem you're trying to solve is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do this the same way that you read any text file, and we can use [sys.argv](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm) to get the argument passed when running the python script.

Ex:

```py
import sys

with open('script.sh', 'r') as sfile:
    modified_file_contents = sfile.read().replace('$1', sys.argv[1])
```

With this method, `modified_file_contents` is a string containing the text of the file, but with the specified variable replaced with the argument passed to the python script when it was run.