# Running a script from another python

Tags: python

I just want to have some ideas to know how to do that...

I have a python script that parses log files, the log name I give it as an argument so that when i want to run the script it's like that.. ( `python myscript.py LOGNAME` ) 
what I'd like to do is to have two scripts one that contains the functions and another that has only the main function so i don't know how to be able to give the argument when i run it from the second script.

---

here's my second script's code:

```
import sys
import os 

path = "/myscript.py"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(path))
import myscript 

mainFunction()
```

---

the error i have is:

```
script, name = argv 
valueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: `path = "./myscript.py"`? Also, this error most likely originates from `myscript.py` and not this script considering you don't even use `sys.argv` in this script

Comment: The error indicates you have 3 arguments in argv but are only unpacking two. Maybe show us more code? (From `myscript`)

Comment: The answer is: Both scrips share the same `sys.argv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python (just as most languages) will share parameters across imports and includes.
Meaning that if you do:

`python mysecondscript.py heeey` that will flow down into `myscript.py` as well.
So, check your arguments that you pass.

**Script one**

```
myscript = __import__('myscript')
myscript.mainfunction()
```

**script two**

```
import sys
def mainfunction():
    print sys.argv
```

And do:

`python script_one.py parameter`

You should get:

> ["script_one.py", "parameter"]

Comment: As mentioned in a comment on snakes solution.
If you need to modify the parameter then do so by supplying `mainfunction()` with a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways of doing it.

```
>>> execfile('filename.py')
```

Check the following link:

[How to execute a file within the python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter)