# module import: NameError: name is not defined

Tags: python, python-import

How do I define the function in the importer so that it is visible inside imported? I tried this

`importer.py` is

```
def build():
    print "building"

build()

import imported
```

Whereby, `imported.py` is simply

```
build()
```

Yet, this fails

```
building
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\valentin\Desktop\projects\maxim\miniGP\b01\evaluator\importer.py", line 6, in <module>
    import imported
  File "C:\Users\valentin\Desktop\projects\maxim\miniGP\b01\evaluator\imported.py", line 1, in <module>
    build()
NameError: name 'build' is not defined
```

**Update** After I have got the response to make the circular import, so that import and imported depend on each other, I feel that I need to make clear that this is not always good. My purpose is to specify some common strategy in the imported module. It will use some user-defined functions, e.g. `build`. User defines the necessary function(s) and calls the strategy. The point is that the shared strategy must not depend on specific user definitions. I believe that in place of `import`, I need something like `evaluate(imported.py)`, which I believe is a basic function in any script language, including Python. irc://freenode/python insists that I must use `import` but I do not understand how.

Comment: Part of our confusion is because that's _exactly what `import` does_, as a side-effect of importing the module itself.  (So, if `foo.py` contains `bar = 1 + 1` and you `import foo`, you then have access to `foo.bar == 2` because `foo.py` was evaluated!)

Comment: I do not understand which confusion you are talking about.

Answer (score -14, accepted):

I know that this is a blasphemy but the thing that allows to import a module without tying the imported with importer is easily available in Python as a script language. You can always evaluate a file with [execfile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027739/1083704)

Comment: `execfile()` isn't "blasphemy", it's a plain bad idea. Also, it's quite unlike importing. It's clear from your question that this is what you want, but it's not clear _why_ you want this. This is not a normal thing to do in Python, by any means. Structure your project to fit Python, instead.

Answer (score 12):

## importer.py

```
def build():
   print("building")

build() #this extra call will print "building" once more.
```

## imported.py

```
from importer import build
build()
```

Note that both importer.py and imported.py must be in same directory. I hope this solve your problem

Comment: Won't it create a curcular reference? How many times is print("building") executed?

Comment: as much as you call build() function. For my case It will print just once.

Comment: In fact, I call it twice and in fact, it is executed 3 times. I wonder why not million: you call importer.py, which prints and imports imported.py, which imports the importer.py, which prints(building) and imports the impoted, which imports the importer, which prints(building) and imports the imported, which …

Comment: Have you tried it yet! using import means to make reference to your module, not to execute it. And a function call build() inside the imported will actually call the function from importer.py which is then executed not more than once. So try it before you ask it

Comment: I have tried it, and in my laptop its just once, and with 2 build() function its twice.. double check your problem I am sure its not the way of python

Comment: All I did is prefix the `imported.py` with the `from importer import build` line that you have recommended

Comment: Then it should be working then, check to your importer.py, may be you have two build() function; one for definition and another one is function call. Its not a problem of import anymore.

Comment: Ok, I have not noticed that you asked me to rewrite the `importer.py` also. The problem was missing `from importer import build` in the `imported.py`. Your answer does not resolve it though. I cannot import the importer because imported is a common piece that must work in any context (arbitrary importer, whichever `build` function it has defined). Imported must not be tied to specific importer.

Comment: I have discovered that I need [execfile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1027739/1083704). Unfortunately enemy does not let me to make this as answer. But let's keep the right answer here.

Comment: @Val If you have multiple implementations of code defining `build`, and only one must be called depending on a certain context, you're not even asking the right question.  You've gone down a rabbit hole in the wrong direction.  Please, in the future, actually ask about the problem you're facing, _not_ what you assume the answer will be.

Comment: @Izkata I asked that at irc://freenode/#python and they told me that I need to single out a common part into another file and use imports. They refused to explain how should I import actually. I, thus, had to resort here. What did I wrong?

Comment: @Val We still don't know what you're trying to do, so this answer was really the best we can do, and it's not what you want.  Please [read this and ask a question about what you're actually trying to do](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), if you still need help.

Comment: @Izkata, I have updated the question explaining the limitation of "the best you can do" and why execfile is more appropriate for my task. I wonder why python experts are so blind to notice that and demand more details without explaining what is not clear in what is provided. I have tired explaining why I need this. I won't do any more. Listen Faynman explaining that there is ultimate reason why you need something http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA I feel that is enough to say that ice is slippery. You ask `why` without even clarifying what are you referring to.

Answer (score 7):

Imports are not includes: they are idempotent and [should always be at the top of a module](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

There is no circularity; once `import foo` is seen, further instances of `import foo` will not load the module again.

You are getting the NameError because in the context of imported.py, there is no name `build`, it is known as `importer.build()`.

I have no idea what you are trying to do with code as oddly structured as that.

Comment: Importer defines some functions and calls some common code. This way you parametrize your common code. There is nothing strange in this normality.