# How can I import a .pyc compiled python file and use it

Tags: python, file, import, include

Im trying to figure out how to include a `.pyc` file in a python script.

For example my script is called:

```
myscript.py
```

and the script I would like to include is called:

```
included_script.pyc
```

So, do I just use:

```
import included_script
```

And will that automatically execute the `included_script.pyc` ? Or is there something further I need to do, to get my `included_script.pyc` to run inside the `myscript.py`?

Do I need to pass the variables used in `included_script.pyc` also? If so, how might this be achieved?

Comment: No that won't execute it automatically. Check out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, **no**, this cannot be done automatically. *You can, of course, do it manually **in a gritty ugly way.***

---

#### Setup:

For demonstration purposes, I'll first generate a `.pyc` file. In order to do that, we first need a `.py` file for it. Our sample `test.py` file will look like:

```
def foo():
    print("In foo")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World")
```

Super simple. Generating the `.pyc` file can done with the **[`py_compile`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/py_compile.html)** module found in the standard library. We simply pass in the name of the `.py` file and the name for our `.pyc` file in the following way:

```
 py_compile.compile('test.py', 'mypyc.pyc')
```

This will place `mypyc.pyc` in our current working directory.

---

#### Getting the code from `.pyc` files:

Now, `.pyc` files contain bytes that are structured in the following way:

- First 4 bytes signalling a 'magic number'
- Next 4 bytes holding a modification timestamp
- Rest of the contents are a *marshalled* [`code`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.CodeType) object.

What we're after is that marshalled `code` object, so we need to **[`import marshal`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/marshal.html)** to un-marshall it and execute it. Additionally, we really don't care/need the 8 first bytes, and un-marshalling the `.pyc` file with them is disallowed, so we'll ignore them (`seek` past them):

```
import marshal

s = open('mypyc.pyc', 'rb')
s.seek(8)  # go past first eight bytes
code_obj = marshal.load(s)
```

So, now we have our fancy `code` object for `test.py` which is valid and ready to be executed as we wish. *We have two options here*:

1. Execute it in the current `global` namespace. This will bind all definitions inside our `.pyc` file in the current namespace and will act as a sort of: `from file import *` statement.
2. Create a new module object and execute the code inside the module. This will be like the `import file` statement.

---

#### Emulating `from file import *` like behaviour:

Performing this is pretty simple, just do:

```
exec(code_obj)
```

This will execute the code contained inside `code_obj` in the current namespace and bind everything there. After the call we can call `foo` like any other funtion:

```
foo()
# prints: In foo!
```

*Note*: `exec()` is a built-in.

---

#### Emulating `import file` like behaviour:

This includes another requirement, the **[`types`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html)** module. This contains the type for **[`ModuleType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.ModuleType)** which we can use to create a new module object. It takes two arguments, the name for the module (mandatory) and the documentation for it (optional):

```
m = types.ModuleType("Fancy Name", "Fancy Documentation")

print(m)
<module 'Fancy Name' (built-in)>
```

Now that we have our module object, we can again use `exec` to execute the code contained in `code_obj` inside the module namespace (namely, `m.__dict__`):

```
exec(code_obj, m.__dict__)
```

Now, our module `m` has everything defined in `code_obj`, you can verify this by running:

```
m.foo() 
# prints: In foo
```

---

These are the ways you can 'include' a `.pyc` file in your module. At least, the ways I can think of. I don't really see the practicality in this but hey, I'm not here to judge.

Comment: While I don't have much confidence, but Python 3.3+ seems to requires another 4 bytes in a head magic munbers, so s.seek(8) needs to be s.seek(12). https://qiita.com/amedama/items/698a7c4dbdd34b03b427

Comment: Am having .pyc file with some like this: def myfunc(in_str = "Hello World"):
    print(in_str)

And I run it using a separate script like this; import marshal
s = open('script2.cpython-37.pyc', 'rb')
s.seek(12) 
code_obj = marshal.load(s)
exec(code_obj)
myfunc()
myfunc("Testing from script4")

It is giving me error: 
(base) C:\Users\ashish\Desktop\code_20210128_1200\2>python script4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script4.py", line 5, in <module>
    code_obj = marshal.load(s)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Comment: In python 3.7 and above, I believe it should be s.seek(16). https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0552/