# How to import Python modules provided by commercial software?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, abaqus

I would like to test Python2 code that depends on objects provided by commercial software Abaqus. I can start the Python interpreter that is shipped with Abaqus via `abaqus python`:

> Python 2.7.3 for Abaqus 2018 (default, Sep  9 2017, 03:28:08)
>
> [GCC 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)] on linux2

The problem is that when I try to import the module `abaqus` provided by Abaqus, I get the error:

> abaqus module may only be imported in the Abaqus kernel process

I found the `.pyc` for the module under `/some/path/` and tried to follow the answer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709390/how-can-i-import-a-pyc-compiled-python-file-and-use-it) to execute the compiled code:

```
import marshal

s = open('/some/path/abaqus.pyc', 'rb')
s.seek(8)  # go past first eight bytes
code_obj = marshal.load(s)
exec(code_obj)
```

But this yields the same error. Is there any way I can import the module **outside** the Abaqus kernel process?

**UPD 1**

I tried launching a subprocess, but to no avail.
I created a file `my_test_script.py`:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call( ["pytest", "--version"] )
```

Running `python my_test_script.py` produces:

```
This is pytest version 4.6.11, imported from /path/to/virtual/environment/pytest.pyc
```

Running the same script through Abaqus results in the following error:

```
$ abaqus cae nogui=my_test_script.py
Abaqus License Manager checked out the following license:
"cae" from Flexnet server licabaq1.lic
<39 out of 40 licenses remain available>.
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/apps/Common/Core/ABAQUS/2018-linux-x86_64/cae/linux_a64/tools/SMApy/python2.7/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/bin/pytest", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 65, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 214, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/hooks.py", line 286, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/manager.py", line 87, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.py", line 94, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 81, in get_result
    _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 789, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 997, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 938, in _preparse
    self._consider_importhook(args)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 886, in _consider_importhook
    self._mark_plugins_for_rewrite(hook)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 908, in _mark_plugins_for_rewrite
    for name in _iter_rewritable_modules(package_files):
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 662, in _iter_rewritable_modules
    package_files = list(package_files)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/config/__init__.py", line 904, in <genexpr>
    if any(ep.group == "pytest11" for ep in dist.entry_points)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 289, in entry_points
    return EntryPoint._from_text(self.read_text('entry_points.txt'))
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 138, in _from_text
    config.read_string(text)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 794, in read_string
    self.read_file(sfile, source)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 789, in read_file
    self._read(f, source)
  File "/path/to/virtual/environment/lib/python2.7/site-packages/backports/configparser/__init__.py", line 1193, in _read
    raise e
backports.configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: u'<string>'
    [line  2]: u'\U00660000\U00320000\U00700000\U00790000\U00200000\U003d0000\U00200000\U006e0000\U00750000\U006d0000\U00700000\U00790000\U002e0000\U00660000\U00320000\U00700000\U00790000\U002e0000\U00660000\U00320000\U00700000\U00790000\U00320000\U00650000\U003a0000\U006d0000\U00610000\U00690000\U006e0000\U000a0000\x00\x00\x00\x00w_MapString1DArrayListInt.'
    [line  3]: u'\U00660000\U00320000\U00700000\U00790000\U00320000\U00200000\U003d0000\U00200000\U006e0000\U00770000config\x00c'
```

The Abaqus replay file does not contain anything helpful for me:

```
# from driverUtils import executeOnCaeGraphicsStartup
# executeOnCaeGraphicsStartup()
#: Executing "onCaeGraphicsStartup()" in the site directory ...
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
session.Viewport(name='Viewport: 1', origin=(1.36719, 1.36719), width=201.25, 
    height=135.625)
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].makeCurrent()
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup
executeOnCaeStartup()
execfile('my_test_script.py', __main__.__dict__)
print 'RT script done'
#: RT script done
```

Any takes on the output?

Comment: Why don't you use the CAE interpreter? I think Abaqus specifically protected their libraries so they can only be used alongside with the CAE licence

Comment: Do you mean that I run the tests from the interactive session? But then I face the problem that my `PyTest` is installed in the virtual environment. And something like `os.system('ml Python; source venv/bin/activate; python -m pytest unit_tests')` does not work. I work on the cluster, you see, and cannot install packages globally.

Comment: If Abaqus is accessible from your virtual environment, then you can launch your test scripts using `subprocess` and the 'abaqus cae nogui=my_test_script.py'. `subprocess` would allow you retrieving log information and consequently use it in unit test I guess

Comment: @RomanZhuravlev it did not work. I updated the post with the error message I received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that finally understood all details of your problem. For example, what are you trying to achieve by executing the code frome a '.pyc' file (btw what does it contain?)?

Anyway, here I am sharing the routine which works for me.

1. Creating a script `my_abaqus_script.py`

> Note: the list of imports can vary depending on your needs

```py
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from part import *
from sketch import *

m = mdb.Model(name='myModel')
a = abq_model.rootAssembly

my_sketch = m.ConstrainedSketch(name='my_sketch', sheetSize=24.0)

pivots = [(0., 0.), (0., 1.), (1., 1.), (1., 0.)]
n = len(pivots)
for i in range(n):
    my_sketch.Line(point1=pivot_pts[i], point2=pivot_pts[(i+1) % n])

my_part = m.Part(dimensionality=THREE_D, name='MyPart', type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
my_part.BaseSolidExtrude(sketch=my_sketch, depth=1.0)

# ...and so on
```

2. Launching the subprocess in your working directory (see the documentation of [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and how to execute abaqus job from the command line at the "Abaqus Analysis User's Guide -> Introduction, Spatial Modeling, and Execution -> Job Execution ->
   Execution procedures"). The following code you launch in any python interpreter.

```py
import subprocess
my_cmd = 'abaqus job=my_abaqus_script analysis cpus=1 interactive'

proc = subprocess.Popen(
   my_cmd,
   cwd=my_working_dir,
   stdout='my_study.log',
   stderr='my_study.err',
   shell=True
)
```

3. If something in the code doesn't work, I am opening the Abaqus CAE and trying to launch the code "by line" in the Abaqus python interpreter (at the bottom of the window). You can investigate different objects there for a better understanding of how Abaqus environment is working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The `.pyc` file contains Abaqus objects (which are imported via `from abaqus import *` in your example). I need them to use in my unit test routines in PyTest. So my question is how do I marry Abaqus with PyTest? Your example shows how to call Abaqus as a subprocess. Do you imply that I should use the status of the `my_abaqus_script` in the `assert` statement of testing routines?

Comment: Well, you could, yes. That this what I am doing: one test for model generation; one test for odb postprocess; etc

Comment: @honey_badger Anything you need from Abaqus has to go through the abaqus.exe process. I don't think you can import Abaqus' libraries from outside, and I don't see why you would want to do that. Furthermore, running unit tests on abaqus scripts (even for complex libraries) is not very productive because: (1) you can't fix API problems; (2) you can generally trust the API to work (except the assembly module, that's really bad); and (3) you can't really isolate the output of your functions because everything is big and time-consuming.