# differential update of pyinstaller executable (modify embedded PYZ-00.pyz)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, archive, zlib, difference

I'm planning to create a huge executable directory and install it on some devices.

Imagine, that lateron I discover a bug in one of  my python modules.
Is there any way to transfer/copy only the modified byte code and replace the original byte code with the new one.

The reason I want to do this is, that in my context bandwidth is very expensive and I'd like to patch the code remotely.

Example: I have a project with two files:
`prog.py`: (with following three  lines)

```
import mod1
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mod1.hello()
```

`mod1.py`: (with following two line)

```
def hello():
    print("hello old world")
```

Now I use `PYTHONHASHSEED=2 pyinstaller prog.py` to create my directory which I copy to my device

Now I modify `mod1.py`:

```
def hello():
    print("hello new world")
```

and I recompile with `PYTHONHASHSEED=2 pyinstaller prog.py`
The full directory has (tared and gzipped) a size of about 10M
The file `dist/prog/prog` has a size of about 1M

with `pyi-archive_viewer` I can extract `PYZ-00.pyz` out of my executable `dist/prog/prog`
In `PYZ-00.pyz` I can find and extract `mod1` which uses only 133 bytes.

Now if I copy that file to my device, how could I update the old
`dist/prog/prog` such, that it has the new `PYZ-00.pyz:mod1` byte code.

What code could I use to decompose, what code could I use to reassemble after having replaced one specific file (module)?

**Alternative: Move pyc files to a zip file**
Startup performance is not that crucial. I could also live with an alternative solution, where no PYZ file is created and added to the executable, but where the dist directory contains a zip file with all the .pyc files

**Another alternative: copy .pyc files into application directory**
This would result in `__file__` having exactly the same value as in the PYZ mode. Performance wise probably not that nice and creating a lot of files, but if incremental updates are crucial perhaps one option to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is neither capable of 'patching' a `.PYZ` file nor capable of putting all `.pyc` files into a zip file.

But so far it is the only viable solution I found so far, that works for huge projects with loads of third party dependencies.

The idea is to remove all (or most files from the .PYZ file) and copy the corresponding .pyc files into the working directory.

I will enhance and elaborate this answer over time. I'm still experimenting:

I achieve this by modyfing the spec file:

- determine the directory `MYDIR` where the spec file is located in
- create a directory, `MYDIR/src` where all the files from `a.pure` shall be copied to
- copy all files from a.pure to to `MYDIR/src`. (with subdirectories corresponding to the module's name.  Module `mypackage.mod.common` would for example be stored in `MYDIR/src/mypackage/mod/common.py`)
- iterate through files and compile them to a `.pyc` file and remove `.py` file afterwards.
- create a `PYZ` file which contains only the files that are not copied. (in my test case, keep no `.pyc` file in the `PYZ`)
- create exe with the modified `PYZ`
- collect all files that should be collected plus also all files from `MYDIR/src` (e.g. with `a.datas + Tree("src")`

**Spec file Changes:**
At the beginning

```
import os
MYDIR = os.path.realpath(SPECPATH)
sys.path.append(MYDIR)
import mypyinsthelpers  # allows to reuse the code in multiple projects
```

Then after the (unmodified) `a = Analysis(...` section I add.

```
to_rmv_from_pyc = mypyinsthelpers.mk_copy_n_compile(a.pure, MYDIR)

# modified creation of pyz`
pyz = PYZ(a.pure - to_rmv_from_pyc, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

I will detail the function `mypyinsthelpers.mk_copy_n_compile` further down

Change the collect phase:

Instead of

```
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
...
```

I write:

```
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas + Tree("src"),
...
```

And here the declaration of `mypyinsthelpers.mk_copy_n_compile()`

```
import compileall
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


def mk_copy_n_compile(toc, src_tree):
    """
    - copy source files to a destination directory
    - compile them as pyc
    - delete source
    """
    dst_base_path = os.path.join(src_tree, "src")
    to_rm = []
    # copy files to destination tree
    for entry in toc:
        modname, src, typ = entry
        assert typ == "PYMODULE"
        assert src.endswith(".py") or src.endswith(".pyw")
        # TODO: might add logic to skip some files (keep them in PYC)
        to_rm.append(entry)

        if src.endswith("__init__.py"):
            modname += ".__init__"

        m_split = modname.split(".")
        m_split[-1] += ".py"
        dst_dir = os.path.join(dst_base_path, *m_split[:-1])
        dst_path = os.path.join(dst_dir, m_split[-1])
        if not os.path.isdir(dst_dir):
            os.makedirs(dst_dir)
        print(entry[:2], dst_path)
        shutil.copy(src, dst_path)

    # now compile all files and rmv src
    top_tree = src_tree
    src_tree = os.path.join(src_tree, "src")
    curdir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(dst_base_path)
    for path in Path(dst_base_path).glob("**/*.py"):
        # TODO: might add code to keep some files as source
        compileall.compile_file(
            str(path.relative_to(dst_base_path)), quiet=1, legacy=True)
        path.unlink()
    os.chdir(curdir)
    return to_rm
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a complex problem, but I think this may be at least part of what you're looking for.

Based on your example, I changed `prog.py` so it imports pretty normally when running from source, but when frozen with pyinstaller runs from `pyc` files directly.

```py
import sys

def import_pyc(name):
    import py_compile
    import types
    import marshal
    
    pyversion = f"{sys.version_info.major}{sys.version_info.minor}"
    filename = f"{name}.cpython-{pyversion}.pyc"
    
    with open(filename, "rb") as pyc_file:
        # pyc files have 16 bytes reserved at the start in python 3.7+
        # due to https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0552/
        # may change again in the future
        pyc_file.seek(16) 
        code_obj = marshal.load(pyc_file)

    module = types.ModuleType(name)
    exec(code_obj, module.__dict__)

    globals()[name] = module

def import_py(name):
    import importlib
    
    globals()[name] = importlib.import_module("mod1")
    
def import2(name):
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        import_pyc(name)
    else:
        import_py(name)


import2("mod1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mod1.hello()
```

This is heavily based on the wonderful answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709390/how-can-i-import-a-pyc-compiled-python-file-and-use-it).

This means that `mod.py` is not packaged by PyInstaller, you will have to include `mod1.cpython-38.pyc` as a data file.

One convenient way to do this is with the command `PyInstaller --add-data "__pycache__/*;." prog.py` (Although switch the semicolon for a colon if you're not on Windows). This puts everything in the `__pycache__` folder, all your imported modules, into your ending `dist/prog` folder. Note that if you run this multiple times PyInstaller puts a pyc for the main python folder in `__pycache__`, so that will get bundled on subsequent runs.

Depending on how you bundle and run your project, you will probably run into problems where the current working directory is off, which will result in a `FileNotFound` when you try to load the `pyc`s. I can't give you a silver bullet to find the path you want, since it depends on how you end up doing things, but ways I commonly use to find the absolute path that should be the current working directory are `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)` and `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`.

Comment: yes this is a rather partial solution and not easy to implement for an existing code base with hundreds of files, as every file had to be modified.

It also doesn't show how to move the .pyc files out of the .PYZ file and into the directory.

I will post an answer which I'm not really happy about, but which seems to provide a working solution. though it patches neither the .PYZ file nor uses a zip file.

Comment: With this, the pyc files never end up in the PYZ archive in the first place, since PyInstaller doesn't know about the imports. Although I'm not sure how this would work with more complicated import mechanics, like modules, which is probably relevant for that many files.

Comment: Yep I see. I have an existing project with several hundreds of files and many third party dependencies, so this approach is not really viable.
I depend on `Pyinstaller`'s analysis phase to know what has to be packaged.

My alternative solution, that I just came up with yesterday is far from nice, but requires no changes in the source code (or only one change in the top level program if I'd like to use zip files) or if I'd like to put all code into a dedicated sub directory

Comment: Now a Stackoverflow specific question.

Id' like to accept my answer as it will probably be more helpful for the ones going through this question in the future.

However I'd like to attribute the bounty to you as yours is the only answer and I'd like to reward your effort.

What are the SO mechanics to achieve this?

Comment: Ah, I missed this earlier. I'm not sure really - I've never done a bounty before. I appreciate the thought, but if it doesn't easily work don't worry about it.

Comment: Found on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

*As of June 2010, the bounty system is decoupled from accepting an answer.*

So I awarded you the bounty and will for the moment accept my answer

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Is my own answer understandable?