# Pyinstaller. how to put all python code into a zip file instead of putting then in an embedded PYZ

Tags: python, pyinstaller, carchive

This question is related to [differential update of pyinstaller executable (modify embedded PYZ-00.pyz)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67019608/differential-update-of-pyinstaller-executable-modify-embedded-pyz-00-pyz)

I would like to create a pyinstaller distributable, that can easily be hot fixed without wasting too much bandwidth.

The standard pyinstaller approach for embedding python code .pyc files seems to be to put them into a PYZ file  (ZLIB archive), adding the PYZ file into a CARchive and append the CArchive to the end of the executable.

I thought, that following solution might help me, tough it will penalize startup time of the program, but this is acceptable.

If possible I would like, that all collected .pyc files will **not** be added tot he .PYZ file but into a normal .zip file and that this normal zip file will then be added ('collected') into the `dist` folder.

How could I achieve this?

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68754754/858675 to the other question is almost there and one could just pack up all .pyc files into a .zip file.

However the value of `__file__` would be different for the modules and I guess, this might break some existing code if the depend on `__file__`