# Automatically run another script after i run main code in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been looking for a feature where PyCharm notifies me that a script has finished running in the console after each run. At present, I have to add `print('done')` after each code.

I got smarter so I defined `d = 'done'` once and after each run I simply add a `d` so it prints out `'done'` which I thought to be more of a time saver.

Now I am even more lazy and whenever I press F10 (my run command button), I want PyCharm to automatically run a small script with `d = 'done'` in it right after finishing running the main script.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you don't get a useful answer, you may want to suggest this as a new feature to the developers of PyCharm.

Comment: why not just run a script that calls these scripts in sequence?  as in here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter

Answer (score -1):

All Intellij-based IDEs support shell integration, scripting, plugins etc. I bet you can insert your notifications in a build script. 
*Run* menu-> *edit configurations*

Actually, CLion shows notification on failed/successful  build, but I did make something like this with PhpStorm.

You're programmer, all the bells and whistles are given, just use them.

Comment: This is not an answer