# Print output to a file using another Python module

Tags: python

I have two python modules: `buildContent.py` which contains code that results in output i want. `buildRun.py` which i run in order to redirect the output to a file.

I'm trying to save the output from `buildContent.py` to a file and I did something like this in the `buildRun.py`:

```
import buildContent
import sys

with open('out.xhtml', 'w') as f:
    sys.stdout = f
print buildContent
```

I can see my output in the console but the file result is:

```
<module 'buildContent' from 'here's my path to the file'>
```

what to do?

Comment: You're trying to print the actual module. Did you want to call a function in `buildContent`? What you're trying to do at the moment is like doing `import sys; print sys`.

Comment: That kinda opened my eyes... So i wrapped everything in a function then call it in `buildRun` and it works! Now the only problem is that i have `None` printed in the last line of the output file.

Comment: Got it... I shouldn't `print` the function. Just calling it is enough.

Answer (score 1):

the redirection is working properly. 
if you replace your print statement with a string you will see that it has 
worked.

The reason for that output is that you are not calling any functions within buildcontent, merely importing it.

The solution is to run the buildContent file from within the above where your print statement should be.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter) for an example

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing `buildContent`, just execute that module with the required parameters. Not sure of the content of `buildContent` but something like this should work:

```
buildContent(data)
```

This way the code inside `buildContent` will run on the `"data"` and print the results (if the print statements are given in the module). If you did not include print statements in `buildContent`, collect the output into a variable and print that variable. Something like this:

```
var = buildContent(data)
print var
```

If you do not need any data atall to run `buildContent`, just run:

```
buildContent()
```