# Interactive Python like Interactive Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

I'm trying to load a ".py" file in Python like I did with a ".rb" file in interactive Ruby. This file runs a code which asks for a user's name, and then prints "Hello (user's name), welcome!". I have searched all over but I can't quite find a solution.

I know how to do this in Ruby, but how can I do this in Python?

**Ruby Code (test.rb)**

```
print "Enter your name:"
input = gets.chomp
puts "Hello " + input + "! Welcome to Ruby!"
```

**Python Code (test.py)**

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print ("Hello" + (name) + "Welcome to Python!")
```

**How I run it in interactive ruby (irb)**

[image]

**So how would I do the same in python?**

[image]

Comment: Read about `import`ing modules in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2 [`execfile("test.py")`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) is equivelant to the Ruby `load "test.rb"`

In Python 3 `execfile` has been removed probably as this isn't usually the recommended way of working. You can do [`exec(open("test.py").read())`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3) but a more common workflow would be to either just run your script directly:

```
python test.py
```

or to `import` your test.py file as a module

```
import test
```

then you can do `reload(test)` to load in subsequent edits - although this is much reliable than just re-running `python test.py` each time for various reasons

This assumes `test.py` is in a directory on your `PYTHONPATH` (or `sys.path`) - typically your shells current folder is already added

Answer (score 1):

You just say `import file_name` in the python interpreter [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-April/068786.html) should help you.  Then `file_name.function_to_run()` of course you don't have to do this step if you have the function calls at the bottom of the script it will execute everything then stop.

Answer (score 1):

## From the command-line

You can use the `-i` option for "interactive". Instead of closing when the script completes, it will give a python interpreter from which you can use the variables defined by your script.

```
python -i test.py
```

## Within the interpreter

Use `exec`

```
exec(open("test.py").read())
```

[Reference thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

You are using python 3

so you do it like this

> name = input("Enter your name: ")
>
> print("Hello " + name + ". Welcome to Python!")

Comment: how does this answer the question??