# "No such file or directory" when executing remote source code

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to execute Python3 code located remotely - e.g. github?

```
script_url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geotheory/c874b88e712006802114a50d08c15c46/raw/1f218c0f4aa26b0596d9ef3b67005f7d4a9c8e99/python-test.py"
exec(open(script_url).read())
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geotheory/c874b88e712006802114a50d08c15c46/raw/1f218c0f4aa26b0596d9ef3b67005f7d4a9c8e99/python-test.py'
```

If there's a question already on this I'll happily delete this one, but I've not found anything.

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) only applies to files that exists on your system's filesystem.  The easiest way is to [download the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243750/download-file-from-web-in-python-3) and then [execute it within Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter).

Comment: this is insecure to do such things, to be honest

Comment: Ah cracked it `import urllib.request` then `exec(urllib.request.urlopen(script_url).read())`

Comment: since `script_url` is not a valid filesystem path, it will give that error.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov Assuming the URL points to safe code, is the risk any different to downloading the script and executing it locally?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like below

```
import urllib

script_url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/geotheory/c874b88e712006802114a50d08c15c46/raw/1f218c0f4aa26b0596d9ef3b67005f7d4a9c8e99/python-test.py"
f = urllib.urlopen(script_url)
data = f.read()
exec(data)
```