# Python import and functions

Tags: python, function, import

I have a python file containing multiple functions. And in another file, I have an array which contains functions name . ***How can I implement array value in the format of functions ***

For example :
1 file  contains

```
def add(a,b)   
   c = a+b
      return c
```

2nd file contains

```
functin_arry = ["add"]
```

Then how can I call 1st file functions into 2nd file format of an array

Comment: I think it's not really clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide more details about what you want the end result to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) `eval` or just a reference to the [function](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/function.html) for accomplishing your task.

1. Using `eval`

   Just define your function & supply your function name as parameter.

   ```
   def add(x,y):
       return(x+y)

   eval("add")(2,3)
   ```

   Make sure that the argument to the eval function is a string. ie, supply your 
   function name eval as a "string" followed by parameters.

   Output would be: 5
2. Using function reference.

   Define your function, add a reference to the function into a dictionary & invoke function from the via dict using it's key.

   ```
   def add(x,y):
       return(x+y)

   dynFuncCalls={"add":add}

   #Reference your function to a dictionary.

   dynFunc["add"](2,3)

   #Call it.
   #Here also, the output would be: 5
   ```

**Note:** Avoid using eval, as it is a "[*dangerous function*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)". It allows a user to execute a arbitrary code & it may compromise your entire system.
So, just don't use it. It is a bad practice.

Use the function referencing, which I've mentioned in method 2. It is plain-simple & secure. (Make sure that you'll handle the KeyError exception).

Answer (score 0):

You can define your first file to have all the functions, for example :

**`file_1.py`**

```
import numpy as np

def func_a(a,b):
    res = a + b
    print("func_a, result : ", res)
    return res

def func_b(a,b):
    res = np.sum(np.array((a,b)))
    print("func_b, result : ", res)
    return res
```

To import them from another file, you'd use `exec(open("file_1.py").read())` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027730/1882542)) and you'd have the contents of the second file to be :

**`file_2.py`**

```
exec(open("file_1.py").read())

a = 1
b = 1 

arr = [func_a,func_b]

for i in arr:
    i(a,b)
```

And then you can run `file_2.py` in a shell by :

```
(ipy3) sajid@DESKTOP-NDBN82B:/mnt/c/Users/sajid/Documents/misc/temp$ python file_2.py
func_a, result :  2
func_b, result :  2   
(ipy3) sajid@DESKTOP-NDBN82B:/mnt/c/Users/sajid/Documents/misc/temp$
```

Comment: Superb..
By this process am able to execute the function ..
But am having array format like this in a string
```arr = ['func_a','func_b']```
when i apply this format it shows 
```TypeError: 'str' object is not callable```

Comment: When you define your array to be `arr=['func_a','func_b']` the contents of the array are strings (as they're nested within single quotes `'func_a'` vs `func_a`). A string is not going to take any inputs as a function does and hence you have the error. 

On the other hand, if you use `arr = [func_a,func_b]` as I did, you're having the contents of the array be functions and not strings. They will thus accept inputs and run as per the function definition.