# How to implement a python script in a Django web app using parameters from a view

Tags: python, html, django

My question about implementing a script into a view in a django web app.

I have a `.py` script that I want to run inside this django web app using the user-supplied data, the `configfile`, the `modelfile` and the choice as command line arguments. The output is then a list with different scores which will then be displayed inside the html (not the part I need help with yet).

So I have 2 forms, one that uploads a ML model and another one (the one I need help with) that uses user-supplied data to run a uploaded model:

```
    class Meta:
        model = MlModel
        fields = [
            'modelname',
            'configfile',
            'modelfile',
            'choice',
        ]

class TestForm(forms.Form):
    testdata = forms.FileField()
    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MlModel.objects.all())
```

My views are as follow, where the test view is where the testing happens:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/mltesting/')
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request,'mltesting/upload.html', context=context)
def test_model(request):
    submitbutton = request.POST.get("submit")
    testdata = ''
    modfile = ''
    confile = ''
    choice = ''
    form = TestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        testdata = request.FILES['testdata']
        model = form.cleaned_data.get('model')
        model = MlModel.objects.get(modelname=model)
        modfile = model.modelfile.path
        confile = model.configfile.path
        choice = model.choice
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    context = {'form': form, 'testdata': testdata, 'submitbutton': submitbutton, 'modelfile':modfile, 'configfile': confile,'choice': choice}
    return render(request,'mltesting/test.html', context=context)
```

And this is the HTML template where the output of the testing is supposed to be:

```
{% block content %}
<p>Compound Protein Interaction Tool</p>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_table }}
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

{% if submitbutton == "Submit" %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am fairly new to Django in general so I apologise for the (probable) bad formulation of my question, but all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the answer from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Make a folder in the same directory, add the py file there and then import the module you want in the view.py.

call the function as you would call any custom module.

** **EDIT** **
Call the script as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31566843/8900853)

```
def test_model(request):

    if form.is_valid():
        testdata = request.FILES['testdata']
        model = form.cleaned_data.get('model')
        model = MlModel.objects.get(modelname=model)
        modfile = model.modelfile.path
        confile = model.configfile.path
        choice = model.choice
    else:
        form = TestForm()

    #########################################
    ###########Here you run your script
    ###########Any variable from the script will be loaded here
    exec(open("./path/toYour/script.py").read(), globals())


    #Add the information you want from the script to the context
    context = {'someVariableFromTheScript':someVariableFromTheScript, 'form': form, 'testdata': testdata, 'submitbutton': submitbutton, 'modelfile':modfile, 'configfile': confile,'choice': choice}
    return render(request,'mltesting/test.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however the script I want to run is a script that takes command line argument which I would run as follows: python3 script.py --modelfile ... --configfile ... --choice ... So it's not a module I want to import.

Comment: Then check this answer, I think this is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter

Comment: and how do you implement this feature in the django context? Where is the script that I want to run saved? Do I save this in the static folder (where my css files are) or is this somewhere else?

Comment: Follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31566843/8900853

If you run your "script.py", python will load the globals (the variables used in the your script) to the current function beeing run, like the "test_model" you have there. 
There you can access it and added to the context and return it to the HTML and render it.