# Trying to run simple script at python prompt but getting an error

Tags: python

**Trying to run simple python file in python prompt but giving an error:**

*content of test.py*

```
print("Trying to print this using .py file on anaconda prompt")
```

*Running file from python prompt*

```
(base) C:\Users\acharbha>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python C:\Users\acharbha\Documents\python\test.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python C:\Users\acharbha\Documents\python\test.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: execfile('test.py')

Comment: You are trying to run a shell/cmd command inside of the python IDLE.

Comment: @jordanm Just curious, how can you tell it's IDLE? It looks like any other REPL to me.

Comment: You are trying to run a shell/cmd command inside of the python console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute in shell: `python test.py`

To execute inside the interpreter: `exec(open("test.py").read())`

This should help:
[How to execute a file within the python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run it within the python interpreter. So just exit that and run the command on the terminal.