# Is it possible to import a module from command line or from python before running a script

Tags: python-3.x, module

I have written a module which re-defines the print function. Is it possible to preimport it in order to redefine print() (with `from [module] import print`) to demonstrate or test it with a program, without having to modify this program ?

Comment: No. Each process is separate.

Comment: Why should it have to be another process ? I wasn't thinking about making it another process. More about chaining like when to chain shell scripts with `. script`

Answer (score 1):

Eureka ! ;-)

One can import a module (here, redefine the print function) and then [chain a new program (./PROGRAM) in the current environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter) by using the command :

```
from MODULE import print
exec(open('./PROGRAM').read())
```

So (in linux) one can do it from command line (or script it) with :

```
python3 -c "from MODULE import print; exec(open('./PROGRAM').read())"
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436198/what-is-an-alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3) also contains useful information on this topic.