# Why am I getting a syntax error whenever I try to run VS code python terminal?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line, terminal

Whenever I try to run the VS code python terminal, I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    & C:/Users/tawsi/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe c:/Users/tawsi/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Untitled-1.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image: Here is a picture of the Error]

How can I fix this?? Please help

Comment: You can't run a Python file from the REPL, it's for typing Python statements.

Comment: Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter). There are multiple ways to run a python script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your current VSCode terminal is in the "Python interactive window", please try to use "`exit()`" to exit this interactive window, and then use the run button to execute the python script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run the python file in the VS Code terminal you install the Code Runner extension, after which you can right click on the workspace and click the "Run Python File in Terminal" option.