# NameError when executing python script using subprocess module but code executing from IDLE

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, nameerror

I was recently using the subprocess module and it's run method to execute os commands through python only and get the output, since I was trying to make a custom command prompt in tkinter.

The way that command prompt handles commands I write into it is as follows -:

1. So when I write a command as input I split it from spaces for e.g.

   INPUT: `cmd exec python test.py`

   OUTPUT: `['cmd', 'exec', 'python', 'test.py'] # i.e. [cmd, arg1, arg2, ...]`
2. Now I convert the above list into a dictionary with two keys -:

   - The first key is 'name' which has the value as the name of the command.
   - The second key is 'args' which is a concatenated string value (of all the other list items except the first list item from the first
     step).

   So it becomes -:

   ```
   command_input = {'name' : 'python', 'args' = 'test.py'} # i.e. {'name': cmd, 'args': concat_str_of_args}
   ```
3. Now the dictionary made in the second process, is passed into a
   module, which interprets the command and it converts it into a
   normal command prompt command(**NOTE: *Previously the command was a custom one based on my own custom made syntax cmd exec command_prompt_command***) in string form and returns it as a dict called
   command_output, with it's args as the list from step 1 ([cmd, arg1,
   arg2.....]).

   Like so -:

   ```
   command_output = my_module.convert_to_cmd_form(command_input) # returns a dictionary like so -: {'args' : ['python', 'test.py']}
   ```

Now I try executing a python script I made to test if this was working, The code for the test file is -:

```
# CODE FOR TEST FILE
print('This is a special test for the terminal cmd integration!')
```

And executing this file by IDLE I get the desired output with no error:

> This is a special test for the interstellar terminal cmd integration!

While when I do the same with my custom command prompt which in the backend uses a special subprocess python script to run this test.py it gives a name error:

[image: Output of test.py using my script]

And I am not able to properly understand the reason for the same the code for executing scripts is somewhat like so:

```
os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
print([command_output['args'][0]], ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]), ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8'))
result = subprocess.run([command_output['args'][0]], input = ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True, env = os.environ, cwd = 'C:')
```

The print statement here was for debugging to check if all values were being parsed as expected.

```
['python'] test.py b'test.py'
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Please include the complete `test.py` with your [mre].  Or enough or it that we can copy and paste into an editor and reproduce your results.

Comment: Actually I would have pasted the traceback but it is a gui I have made on which the output is showing where the text is displayed in a tkinter listbox and not selectable.

Comment: Also the complete code of test.py has been given theres only 1 line

Comment: Also thanks for the info about the proper way of posting tracebacks I'll surely keep in mind next time I post a question. Unfortunately in here the traceback cannot be copied exactly from the gui element and thus I have provided a screenshot.

Comment: Your question does not show the code that uses `subprocess` to run the script. Please add that.

Comment: Its there the result = subprocess.run line is the one

Comment: os.environ["PYTHONUNBUFFERED"] = "1"
print('BLAHDEHDEUFUFH', [command_output['args'][0]], ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]), ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8'), 'FI4IFJ4IUFH4UFH4F')
result = subprocess.run([command_output['args'][0]], input = ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell = True, env = os.environ, cwd = 'C:')

Comment: This part of the code is there in the question too and is having the last line as subprocess code

Comment: So `test.py b'test.py' FI4IFJ4IUFH4UFH4F` **is** `' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8')`??

Comment: No its the result of the print statement at the top

Comment: print('BLAHDEHDEUFUFH', [command_output['args'][0]], ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]), ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8'), 'FI4IFJ4IUFH4UFH4F') its output of this line

Comment: If `command_output = {'args':['python','test.py', b'test.py', 'FI4IFJ4IUFH4UFH4F']}` then I get - `TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, bytes found` for `' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: Voting to close for lacking an [mre] - I, at least, cannot piece together what you are executing to cause your problem.

Comment: Kindly read the question description carefully before voting all info regarding the problem has been provided.

Comment: The print command is not just printing command_output's element rather also the encoded and decoded part, perhaps you are not calmly and carefully reading the code I've given or else it all makes sense except the error I've got. We can talk further in chat.

Comment: The .encode func has been used by me to encode it into bytes in the print statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225563/discussion-between-wwii-and-matrix-programmer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my special subprocess python script to run this test.py it gives a name error:

Your mre from chat discussion:

```
import subprocess

command_output = {'args':['python',r'test.py'] }
result = subprocess.run([command_output['args'][0]],
                        input = ' '.join(command_output['args'][1 : ]).encode('utf-8'),
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        shell = True, env = os.environ, cwd = 'C:')
```

Include the full path to the file to alleviate the `NameError: name \'test\' is not defined\r\n'` Exception.

```
command_output = {'args':['python',r'c:\full\path\test.py'] }
```

---

For the following solutions you would need to parse `command_output` appropriately.

This form works

```
args = ['python', '-m', 'test']
other = subprocess.run([args,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                        shell = True, env = os.environ, cwd = 'C:')
```

Using the input keyword argument, you need to *send* the python commands you would use if you were typing/executing from a python shell.

```
args = [b'python']
cmd = b'import test'
another = subprocess.run(args,
                         input = cmd,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                         shell = True, env = os.environ, cwd = 'C:')
```

This one courtesy of this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1027739/2823755. Again you may need to include the full path to the file.

```
args = [b'python']
cmd = b'''exec(open("test.py").read())'''
another1 = subprocess.run(args,
                         input = cmd,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                         shell = True, env = os.environ, cwd = 'C:')
```

Comment: The file itself resides in the C: directory only

Comment: Thx, I got it to work now I guess it was the cwd command that was not working and the current working directory was not changing thus it was picking up a local file and not the one in C: drive despite passing cwd arg as C: but as you mentioned writing full path makes it work! Thx

Comment: Now, if you think the question is understandable and can be useful to others in need please vote for reopening of the question.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer: Sure ... but your question may need more detail - when I read your current edit I was still confused and had to review our chat discussion - which I based my answer on.  Feel free to retract the *acceptance* if that is possible. If you came up with your own solution: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Kindly review the question once more and tell me if its suitable now to be opened up again.