# No module in called subprocess (library "subprocess" can't call a py-file with third-party module)

Tags: python, subprocess

I use the subprocess library and call another py file, but I get the error:

```
No module named 'requests'
```

I have this library installed and used in the called file.
If I import this in the main file, it will still be the same error.
With other third-party libraries, the same errors
I use:

```
subprocess.call(['python', 'exchange.py'])
```

Comment: Why are you running Python from within itself as a subprocess, anyway? Clearly the subprocess gets a different environment, but you don't reveal anything about where the modules are installed or how the `sys.path` in the subprocess differs from the one in your main Python script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158662/nameerror-when-executing-python-script-using-subprocess-module-but-code-executin

Comment: instead of 'python', you could use sys.executable.