# Invalid Syntax Error when running Python script on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the Python script that I wrote for scraping a particular website, and then I need to get notified with an email when the price reaches a specific number, for that matter I used PythonAnywhere, but when I run my script in the console, I get the following error, even though it runs normally on Pycharm:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 main.py
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import smtplib


response = requests.get("https://order.badinanshipping.com/profile/b763bd64-1064-426a-b949-d8e5232919ee/invoice")
badini_page = response.text


def send_email(email, password, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email, password)
    server.sendmail(email, email, message)
    server.quit()

soup = BeautifulSoup(badini_page, "html.parser")
price = soup.find(class_="my-box2")
net_price = int(price.getText().split("IQD")[0])


if net_price > 75000:
    send_email("myEmail", "myPassword",
               "\n\n*******\n\n Go pick them up, now! \n\n*******\n\n")
```

Comment: Note: "scrapping" is something different than "scraping".

Comment: Your issue is probably not with the code but with the way you have deployed it on PythonAnywhere

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're running python command inside the python interpreter.

```
Python 3.7 (default)
[Clang 4.0 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python3' is not defined
>>> python3 main.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python3 main.py
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You can open the terminal and type in your command or try

```
>>> exec(open("./main.py").read())
```

[How to execute a file within the Python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027714/how-to-execute-a-file-within-the-python-interpreter)

Comment: I ran that code, but nothing happens, it's just stuck at the new line..

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that command in the bash console, not in the python console.

Comment: I ran it in bash console and I got this error: requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='order.badinanshipping.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /profile/b763bd64-
1064-426a-b949-d8e5232919ee/invoice (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden')))

Comment: It looks like you're running in a free PythonAnywhere account and are trying to access a site that is not on the whitelist: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/