# Run a Python script from another Python script, passing in arguments

Tags: python

I want to run a Python script from another Python script. I want to pass variables like I would using the command line.

For example, I would run my first script that would iterate through a list of values (0,1,2,3) and pass those to the 2nd script `script2.py 0` then `script2.py 1`, etc.

I found [Stack Overflow question 1186789](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186789/what-is-the-best-way-to-call-a-python-script-from-another-python-script) which is a similar question, but ars's answer calls a function, where as I want to run the whole script, not just a function, and balpha's answer calls the script but with no arguments. I changed this to something like the below as a test:

```
execfile("script2.py 1")
```

But it is not accepting variables properly. When I print out the `sys.argv` in script2.py it is the original command call to first script "['C:\script1.py'].

I don't really want to change the original script (i.e. script2.py in my example) since I don't own it.

I figure there must be a way to do this; I am just confused how you do it.

Comment: If os.system isn't powerful enough for you, there's [the subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

Comment: The question is if you know the name of the script (then import it) or if you do not know the name of the script at programming time (then use subprocess.call). In the second case this question also would not be a duplicate. Because the question doesn't make it clear, it's also not really a good one.

Comment: @Trilarion: wrong. You can import a python module even if its name is generated at runtime.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Okay. As a side remark: This way is not really covered well by any answer here or in the linked question, except partly in http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186840/1536976.

Comment: @Trilarion: why should it be covered at all? The names are fixed in both questions. Anyway, the statement *"if you do not know the name of the script at programming time (then use subprocess.call)."* is wrong regardless. If you have a new question; [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Agreed again. I don't have any question right now. If I come up with one I will surely ask.

Comment: @Oli4 "definitely" is a strong word. Care to elaborate? I see subprocess.call() solution that accepts passing multiple command line arguments. I see `import` being mentioned for cases where main() function is defined (it won't help OP but it is the right way for many other people with a similar problem). I see execfile() for Python 2 that uses whatever you put into `sys.argv` (admittedly that last bit is  not mentioned explicitly) — this option should be ignored by beginners. There is even an explicit os.system() answer with multiple arguments (the answer that is  accepted here).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian After your elaboration, I am tempted to agree with you. Even though the other question does not explicitly specify how to send arguments or that it is required, the questions are indeed similar. Sometimes by asking a question differently different solutions appear as ChrisAdams's answer solved my problem. I apologize for my earlier statement saying that this is indeed not a duplicate, and thank you.

Answer (score 421, accepted):

Try using [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system):

```
os.system("script2.py 1")
```

`execfile` is different because it is designed to run a sequence of Python statements in the *current* execution context. That's why `sys.argv` didn't change for you.

Comment: I believe it's generally preferable to use `subprocess.Popen` over `os.system`: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system.

Comment: Yes, that's what the help for `os.system` says. However, for simple uses `os.system` is the simplest way to get the job done. It depends on what your needs are, of course.

Comment: You can also use subprocess.check_call().

Comment: You have to add python to run the script: os.system("python script2.py 1")

Comment: So if I wanted to start 5 threads, I'd just paste that line 5 times into a file, then call that file from cron?

Comment: @macdonjo: No, the `os.system()` call waits until the thing you called finishes before continuing. You could use `subprocess.Popen()` and manage the new processes yourself, or use the `multiprocessing` module, or various other solutions.

Comment: This waits for the callback though, I think you need to use subprocesss

Comment: @GregHewgill - Is there any dynamic way to pass variable's `value` in `os.system("script2.py myvariable")` ? (Note: myvariable keeps changing, so can't pass static value)

Comment: @H.U.: Please see [Passing a variable, set by the user, as a parameter for a os.system() command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715419/passing-a-variable-set-by-the-user-as-a-parameter-for-a-os-system-command) for specific help with that.

Comment: I encounter the issue `sh: 1: *.py: not found`. Add **python** and then it works, i.e., `os.system("python script2.py 1")`.

Comment: @SparkandShine: In the original question, `script2.py` is executable. If it's not executable, you will need to do what you say. Better would be to use `sys.executable`, which is the name of the *current* Python executable (in case it is different from the default one). So something like: `os.system(sys.executable + " script2.py 1")`

Comment: @GregHewgill thx, for me, the permission of the python script is `755` and `script2.py` begins with `#!/usr/bin/env python`. BTW, `os.system(sys.executable + " script2.py 1")` also occurs `sh: 1: *.py: not found`.

Comment: how can I pass location as an argument in my case the file has to be executed with location like this `CapGenVoice.py -i "C:\Users\Ajax\proDem1\a (4).jpg"` ?

Comment: `os.system("python3 script2.py")` actually worked for me, `os.system("script2.py 1")` was giving me weird errors

Comment: Do you know more about reentrance of python? How much instances could I run?. I oberseved crashes in 3.5.2_32bit.

Comment: but will this still work if we convert our program to `.exe` and run on a machine which does not have `python` installed ?

Answer (score 139):

Ideally, the Python script you want to run will be set up with code like this near the end:

```
def main(arg1, arg2, etc):
    # do whatever the script does


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])
```

In other words, *if* the module is called from the command line, it parses the command line options and then calls another function, `main()`, to do the actual work. (The actual arguments will vary, and the parsing may be more involved.)

If you want to call such a script from another Python script, however, you can simply `import` it and call `modulename.main()` directly, rather than going through the operating system.

`os.system` will work, but it is the roundabout (read "slow") way to do it, as you are starting a whole new Python interpreter process each time for no raisin.

Comment: Re: "no raisin." This is not an error. However, it was interesting to see how long it would take for someone unfamiliar with *Futurama* to "correct" it in a random Stack Overflow question: two years and three months.  :-)

Comment: I laughed at "no raisin" simply because it was a ridiculous typo, then saw your comment and found a clip on YouTube.  Even funnier.

Comment: I had a script with no main, but was able to introduce like so: 1. Separate function defs and standalone statements  2. Do the argument parsing under the "if __name__..." section  3. indent the rest of statements under def main(...) and have that logic operate on the method parameters.    Then I was able to call the main method from another script (ex: A unit test)

Comment: Yeah, Python really makes that kind of refactoring pretty easy. I have done similar things more than once myself!

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me if the main program has optional parameters. Here I get "list index out of range". Better have a `Main(sys.argv)` and handle the list of arguments in Main

Comment: "This approach doesn't work for me if the main program has optional parameters" -- if your parsing is at all complicated you should be using the `argparse` module anyway.

Comment: Here we are again nearly 5 years later, and I was delighted to find your quote from that Fry-befuddled brain from Futurama.

Comment: whoa, 2 years...an unraisinable length of time!

Comment: I just saw this in 2023 and it is still riddled with plot holes and spelling errors.

Answer (score 138):

This is inherently the wrong thing to do. If you are running a Python script from another Python script, you should communicate through Python instead of through the OS:

```
import script1
```

In an ideal world, you will be able to call a function inside `script1` directly:

```
for i in range(whatever):
    script1.some_function(i)
```

If necessary, you can hack `sys.argv`. There's a neat way of doing this using a context manager to ensure that you don't make any permanent changes.

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def redirect_argv(num):
    sys._argv = sys.argv[:]
    sys.argv=[str(num)]
    yield
    sys.argv = sys._argv

with redirect_argv(1):
    print(sys.argv)
```

I think this is preferable to passing all your data to the OS and back; that's just silly.

Comment: It might be the "wrong" thing to do but what if the script you need to reference has no main or functions.... an import would execute the script at the time of import, which probably isn't what you want (and you don't want to refactor it because people are also using that script as is).  os/subprocess could deal with such a case

Comment: True... but that's a different question IMO!

Comment: Won't that fail for multithreaded scripts?

Comment: @MarioVilas probably, yes.

Comment: Your method doesn't work for multithreading. I'm trying to run the same file 10 times at the same time.

Comment: @DanS: it does work. You could [use `multiprocessing`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)

Comment: From a higher-level perspective, it's "wrong" to call this strategy "wrong".  When a system scales up, having detailed knowledge of the inner workings of components becomes a larger and larger problem -- a program written in Python might get redesigned in another language, and using the generic process communication facilities of the operating system has much to offer as a strategy.

Comment: It's worth to note that you may import right in the middle of the code, it doesn't have to be placed at the top, @DanS

Comment: ... and what about dependencies? If each script has its own dependencies why the first script should to know all the sencond's script dependencies? From the point of view of architecture, what is wrong is to call directly importing in python (IMHO)

Comment: Also, for neatness, I like to have my scripts in a `bin` directory instead of strewn all around the root directory of the project. In order to import scripts from `bin`, I'd have to add an `__init__.py` to the `bin` directory which seems wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by `permanent changes`?

Answer (score 63):

I think the good practice may be something like this;

```
import subprocess
cmd = 'python script.py'

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate() 
result = out.split('\n')
for lin in result:
    if not lin.startswith('#'):
        print(lin)
```

according to documentation 
The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:

```
os.system
os.spawn*
os.popen*
popen2.*
commands.*
```

Use communicate() rather than .stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling up and blocking the child process.
[Read Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system)

Answer (score 53):

SubProcess module:
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("script2.py 1", shell=True)
```

With this, you can also redirect stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Comment: Do not use `shell=True` unless necessary.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost could you elaborate on that? Edit: For anyone curious, here's an explanation on why:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess

Answer (score 41):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(" python script2.py 1", shell=True)
```

Comment: You might wish to expand on your answer to explain why this is a better option than some of the other answers presented here.

Comment: How to pass argument but not as string, for example list? Is there other option than pass every element separately?

Comment: Do not use shell=True unless necessary.