# Passing a variable, set by the user, as a parameter for a os.system() command

Tags: python

Okay so basically I am quite new at Python, however, I would like to make a simple menu system for all my basic tools I use at work my code so far is below:

```
import os
def main():
    print "Main Menu.\n"
    print "1. Ping yourself.\n"
    print "2. Ping someone else.\n"
    opt = raw_input ("Please enter a number:- ")
    if opt == "1":
            os.system('ping 127.0.0.1')
    if opt == "2":
            ip = raw_input ("Please enter IP:- ")
            os.system('ping'.ip)

main()
```

Now, that all runs fine, however I seem to be stuck on this line here:

```
os.system('ping'.ip)
```

As I would like to use the variable on line 10 to be used in the command. Hope this is an easy fix.

Thanks,

Ross.

Answer (score 7):

You need a space, and the string concatenation operator is `+`, not `.`:

```
os.system("ping " + ip)
```

You can also use string formatting:

```
os.system("ping %s" % ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between the command and the argument.

Answer (score -3):

Once you get it working properly, what happens if the user enters:

```
127.0.0.1; rm -rf /
```