# Can I run a python file within another python file?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Run a python script from another python script, passing in args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args)

Suppose I have script2.py that returns a int value.

Is it possible to run only script.py on my shell and within script.py gets in some way the int value returned by script2.py according to parameters I passed to script.py?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible. That's what modules are used for :).

First you have to put the method that you use in script2.py into a function. I'll use the same example as the person above me has used (because it's a good example :p).

```
def myFunction(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Now on your script.py, you'll want to put:

```
import script2
```

at the top. This will only work if both files are in the same directory.

To use the function, you would type:

```
# Adding up two numbers
script2.myFunction(1, 2)
```

and that should return 3.

Answer (score 0):

Could [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) be what you're after? `execfile('script2.py')` will work as if you had copied and pasted the entire contents of `script2.py` into the console.

e.g. suppose `script2.py` has:

```
 def myFunction(a, b):
     return a + b
```

and then in `script.py` I could do:

```
 # reads in the function myFunction from script2.py
 execfile('script2.py')
 myFunction(1, 2)
```

If you want to execute `script2.py` with parameters passed in from `script.py` then I suggest that the contents of `script2.py` are encased in a function. That is, if your `script2.py` is:

```
a = 1
b = 2
result = a + b
```

I'd suggest you convert it into:

```
 def myFunction(a, b):
     return a + b
```

so that you can specify `a` and `b` from `script.py`.

Comment: Why would you use `execfile` to import a function rather than `import`?

Comment: maybe they have non-function objects that need to be called?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import subprocess

x = 55

print "running bar.py..."
subprocess.call("python bar.py " + x)
```