# How to include a file location in .py file?

Tags: python, file, terminal

```
$ cat a.py
'/t.py'
$ cat /t.py
print 'hello world';
```

What I did is here :

```
$ chmod +x a.py  # made a.py executable
$ ./a.py         # and run it
```

This caused my PC to freeze. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you computer did *not* hang because  you included a location of a file in your python script. show us your code.

Comment: PadraicCunningham t.py is a simple python test file name

@shx2 root@algosig:/usr/bin# cat a.py
'/t.py'

root@algosig:/usr/bin# cat /t.py
print 'hello horld'; 
 What i did is here :
root@algosig:/usr/bin# chmod +x a.py made a.py executable 
root@algosig:/usr/bin# ./a.py and run it 

afterwards terminal aswell as pc  got frozen

Comment: You need a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). Also, please edit your post instead of adding a comment so we can read your code.

Comment: Please edit your Question with the code.

Comment: Oh, and writing `'/t.py'` in Python doesn’t do anything. Do you need a shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Without a shebang (e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of each script, your code will not be interpreted as python unless you do something like `python a.py`. If this was intended, you should change the name to something more useful, like `a.sh` for a shell script.
2. If your file `a.py` *was* interpreted as python, it would do nothing. The string literal `'/t.py'` by itself doesn't do anything useful. If you want to run the file `/t.py`, then you have a couple of options, which are discussed in some depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3781851/2088135). One of the simplest would be to use `execfile`.

Changing `a.py` to the following should do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
execfile('/t.py')
```

As an aside, you really shouldn't be logged into your box as the root user and it's generally not considered good housekeeping to put files at the root of your filesystem.

I'm really not sure why what you were doing originally was causing your computer to hang.