# How to run a particular python script present in any other directory after a "if" statement in a python script?

Tags: python, if-statement

I need to know how to run a python script from a python script present in other directory like the following algorithm:

```
if option==true
 run /path/to/the/directory/PYTHON SCRIPT
else
```

Comment: See this link [run python script within another python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args)

Answer (score 1):

ch3ka points out that you can use `exec` to do this. There are other ways like `subprocess` or `os.system` as well.

But Python works well with itself by design - this is the entire concept behind creating and importing modules. I think for most cases you'd be better off just encapsulating the script in a class, and moving the code that was previously in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section of the script into the `__init__` section of the class:

```
class PYTHON_SCRIPT:
     def __init__(self):
         # put your logic here
```

Then you could just import the class:

```
import PYTHON_SCRIPT

# no need to say if a boolean is true, just say if boolean
if option:
    PYTHON_SCRIPT()
```

This would additionally give you the benefit of being able to use properties within your script as you saw fit.

Answer (score 0):

use `execfile`.

> execfile(...)
>       execfile(filename[, globals[, locals]])
>
> ```
> Read and execute a Python script from a file.
> The globals and locals are dictionaries, defaulting to the current
> globals and locals.  If only globals is given, locals defaults to it.
> ```

In pyton3, `execfile` is gone. You can use `exec(open('/path/to/file.py').read())` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I dint get that!!

Comment: This is possibly the worst recommendation you could make. `exec` is bad, and should be avoided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933451/why-should-exec-and-eval-be-avoided

Answer (score 0):

Already answered here
[How do I execute a program from python? os.system fails due to spaces in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204017/how-do-i-execute-a-program-from-python-os-system-fails-due-to-spaces-in-path)

use subprocess module

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\Temp\\a b c\\Notepad.exe', 'C:\\test.txt'])
```

other methods include making system calls using os library or execfile in the other post

Answer (score 0):

if the script is well designed it probably just launch a main function (often called main), so the most proper way to do this is to import this main function in your code and call it, this is the pythonic way. You just need to add the directory of the script into your python path.

if it's possible, always try to avoid exec, subprocess, os.system, Popen etc ..

example :

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'path/to/the/directory')
import python_script
sys.path.pop(0)

if option:
    python_script.main()
```