# Can't access sqlite3 database from python 3.4.2 scripts

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.4

I am trying to write create a sqlite3 database using python 3.4.2 called "podcasts". I created two files:

dbcreate.py:

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table podcasts(name text, hosts text, channel text)")
print("table created")
```

dbinsert.py:

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('insert into podcasts values("Invisibilia","NPR", "Lulu Miller and Alix Spiegel")')
cursor.execute('insert into podcasts values("Hanselminutes", "independent", "Scott Hanselman")')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

When I ran the module for dbcreate.py, it printed "table created" like it should. But when I ran the module for dbinsert.py, I got no output. So I then went to the command line on my Macbook Air and when I entered the python3.4 shell and wanted to access both files from the command line, I got:

```
>>> dbcreate.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in module
NameError: name 'dbcreate' is not defined
```

and:

```
>>> dbinsert.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stdin", line 1, in module
NameError: name 'dbinsert' is not defined
```

When I tried accessing the database from sqlite3 in the command line by typing in .databases, I get:

[image]

I don't know how to access the database I created in dbinsert.py so I would appreciate any help you can give me. Thank you.

Comment: For how to run a Python script from inside Python, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args). The Windows console allows copying/pasting text. And what output did you expect?

Comment: I'm using a Macbook (Apple) command line. The output I'm expecting are the values that I put inside the conn.execute lines: "Invisibilia", "NPR", and "Lulu Miller and Alix Spiegel", and "Hanselminutes", "independent", and "Scott Hanselman".

Comment: Why would you try to open a Python script inside the sqlite3 shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run your `.py` files from within the Python shell, which will not work. Instead, from the command line, run

```
python3 dbcreate.py
python3 dbinsert.py
```

assuming that `python3` points to your installation of Python 3.4.2. This will execute your code, creating the `.db` file and inserting the values you indicated.

There will be no output from `dbinsert.py`, as you are not printing anything, just executing database commands.

Comment: I got /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'dbcreate.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @user907 are you in the directory where the files are?

Comment: You were right, there was no output in dbinsert.py. I accessed the right directory.