# Running a script from within a Python script

Tags: python, subprocess, os.system

I am attempting to run a python script located in a folder on my server from another python script. The location of the script I am attempting to run is not in the same location as the existing script.  The script I am trying to execute is not a function I just need it to start once the first one has completed, and I know they both work independently of each other.  I have found a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args) but I get the error `Not Found` when I use either `os.system` or `subprocess.Popen`.

I know that  the directory I am calling is correct because in the previous statement I call a `shutil.move` to move a file to the same directory the scipt I would like to run is in.

This is what I have tried:

```
subprocess.Popen("/home/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xx/test.py")

os.system("/home/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xx/test.py")

subprocess.Popen("/home/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xx/test.py", shell=True)
```

Comment: os.chdir() will let you move to the location of the other python script

Comment: What do you think happens when you run *.py file? Clearly test.py does not have python interpreter in it's source code...

Comment: @NSH wrong the test.py script works

Comment: @Dan get the current directory you are in. Change the directory using os.chdir(), run the script, go back to the directory you were in

Comment: @Dan That's not their point, they are saying that `/home/xxx/xxx/xxx/test.py` is not a command. these things you're trying jsut run these commands, they don't know they're python scripts.

Comment: @will you can run python that way as long as it has executable permissions

Comment: @heinst this is only important if the script does things related to it's location / where it's run from.

Comment: and it has the shebang at the top, yes.

Comment: @will gotta love the shebang

Comment: @will It does do things related to its location I do not want to set up multiple time managers I just want 3 scripts to run sequentially

Comment: @Dan then my answer should work well for you

Comment: @heinst Can you post it as answer and I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a script that does operations related to its location, you will want to first get the current directory you are in using `originalDir = os.path.dirname(full_path)`. Next you will want to use `os.chdir('/home/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xx/')` and then do a `subprocess.Popen("python test.py", shell=True)` to run the script. Then do an `os.chdir(originalDir)` to get back to the directory you once were in.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
original_dir = os.getcwd()
script_paths = ["/...path1.../script1.py", "/...path2.../script2.py", "/...path3.../script3.py"]

for script_path in script_paths:
  base_path, script = os.path.split(script_path)
  os.chdir(original_dir)
  subprocess.Popen(script)


os.chdir(original_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

To run a script as a subprocess in its directory, use `cwd` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from subprocess import check_call

script_path = "/home/xxx/xxxx/xxx/xx/test.py"
check_call([sys.executable or 'python', script_path],
           cwd=os.path.dirname(script_path))
```

The difference from `os.chdir()`-based solution is that `chdir()` is called only in the child process. The parent working directory stays the same.

`sys.executable` is a python executable that executes the parent Python script. If `test.py` have a correct shebang set and the file has executable permissions then you could run it directly (use `[script_path]` *without* `shell=True`).