# Calling a python script with input within a python script using subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a script `a.py` and while executing it will ask certain queries to user and frame the output in json format. Using python subprocess, I am able to call this script from another script named `b.py`. Everything is working as expected except that I am not able to get the output in a variable? I am doing this in Python 3.

Comment: As you said, I am importing a.py and running the function. Not using subproceess. Please post your comment as an answer so thatI I can accept it. I am sure It will help newbies like me.

Comment: related: [What is the best way to call a python script from another python script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1186789/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To call a Python script from another one using `subprocess` module and to pass it some input and to get its output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
from subprocess import check_output

script_path = os.path.join(get_script_dir(), 'a.py')
output = check_output([sys.executable, script_path],
                      input='\n'.join(['query 1', 'query 2']),
                      universal_newlines=True)
```

where [`get_script_dir()` function is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22881871/4279).

A more flexible alternative is to import module `a` and to call a function, to get the result (make sure `a.py` uses `if __name__=="__main__"` guard, to avoid running undesirable code on import):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import a # the dir with a.py should be in sys.path

result = [a.search(query) for query in ['query 1', 'query 2']]
```

You could use `mutliprocessing` to run each query in a separate process (if performing a query is CPU-intensive then it might improve time performance):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from multiprocessing import freeze_support, Pool
import a

if __name__ == "__main__":
   freeze_support()
   pool = Pool() # use all available CPUs
   result = pool.map(a.search, ['query 1', 'query 2'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way than mentioned, is by using the built-in funtion `exec`
This function gets a string of python code and executes it
To use it on a script file, you can simply `read` it as a text file, as such:

```
#dir is the directory of a.py
#a.py, for example, contains the variable 'x=1'
exec(open(dir+'\\a.py').read())
print(x) #outputs 1
```