# Pythonic way to detach a process?

Tags: python, subprocess, detach, etcd

I'm running an `etcd` process, which stays active until you kill it. (It doesn't provide a daemon mode option.) I want to detach it so I can keep running more python.

What I would do in the shell;

```
etcd & next_cmd
```

I'm using python's `sh` library, at the enthusiastic recommendation of the  whole internet. I'd rather not dip into `subprocess` or `Popen`, but I haven't found solutions using those either.

What I want;

```
sh.etcd(detach=True)
sh.next_cmd()
```

or

```
sh.etcd("&")
sh.next_cmd()
```

Unfortunately `detach` is not a kwarg and `sh` treats `"&"` as a flag to `etcd`.

Am I missing anything here? What's the good way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To implement `sh`'s `&`, avoid cargo cult programming and use `subprocess` module directly:

```
import subprocess

etcd = subprocess.Popen('etcd') # continue immediately
next_cmd_returncode = subprocess.call('next_cmd') # wait for it
# ... run more python here ...
etcd.terminate() 
etcd.wait()
```

This ignores exception handling and your talk about "daemon mode" (if you want to implement a daemon in Python; use [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/). To run a process as a system service, use whatever your OS provides or a supervisor program such as [`supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html)).

Comment: Using `subprocess.Popen('python file.py')` on Windows returns `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python file.py'`. What could be the problem?

Comment: It looks like a good *separate* question. Related: [Calling a python script with input within a python script using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)

Comment: @Dr_Zaszuś Try adding `shell=True` as a kwarg to your Popen call since the command has multiple words.  Or you can pass the words as a list of strings. https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Answer (score 3):

Author of sh here.  I believe you want to use the `_bg` special keyword parameter http://amoffat.github.io/sh/#background-processes

This will fork your command and return immediately.  The process will continue to run even after your script exits.

Answer (score 2):

subprocess is easy enough to do this too:

This approach works (python3). The key is using "start_new_session=True"

UPDATE: despite Popen docs saying this works, it does not. I found by forking the child and then doing os.setsid() it works as I want

client.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("python3 child.py", shell=True, start_new_session=True)
i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    print("demon: %d" % i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

child.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
import subprocess
import os

pid = os.fork()
if (pid == 0):
    os.setsid()

    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        print("child: %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        if i == 10:
            print("child exiting")
            break
```

output:

```
./client.py
demon: 1
child: 1
demon: 2
child: 2
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "./client.py", line 9, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
KeyboardInterrupt

$ child: 3
child: 4
child: 5
child: 6
child: 7
child: 8
child: 9
child: 10
child exiting
```

Comment: looks like you copy-pasted this answer in all similar stackoverflow questions, but it's not correct - it does not detach the subprocess from it's parent, it simply creates a subprocess (on linux, python 3.8)

Comment: Bit confused as the Popen docs say "If start_new_session is true the setsid() system call will be made in the child process prior to the execution of the subprocess. (POSIX only)"  And "The setsid() library function allows a process to disassociate itself from its parent:". So it "should" be working.  Admittedly I tested on mac. Ok I need to check...

Comment: You're correct...  Ok I found a workaround by forking in the child again and doing os.setsid. That seems to work - can you confirm ? This does sound like a Popen bug as I've seen in many places "As of Python 3.2, you can use subprocess.Popen() and pass start_new_session=True to accomplish fully detach the child process from the parent."

Answer (score 1):

Note in the following two examples there is a call to
`time.sleep(...)` to give `etcd` time to finish starting up before we
send it a request.  A real solution would probably involving probing
the API endpoint to see if it was available and looping if not.

### Option 1 (abusing the `multiprocessing` module):

```
import sh
import requests
import time

from multiprocessing import Process

etcd = Process(target=sh.etcd)

try:
    # start etcd
    etcd.start()
    time.sleep(3)

    # do other stuff
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:4001/v2/keys/')
    print r.text
finally:
    etcd.terminate()
```

This uses the `multiprocessing` module to handle the mechanics of
spawning a background tasks.  Using this model, you won't see the
output from `etcd`.

### Option 2 (tried and true):

```
import os
import signal
import time
import requests

pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    # start etcd
    os.execvp('etcd', ['etcd'])

try:
    # do other stuff
    time.sleep(3)
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:4001/v2/keys/')
    print r.text
finally:
    os.kill(pid, signal.SIGTERM)
```

This uses the traditional `fork` and `exec` model, which works just as
well in Python as it does in C.  In this model, the output of `etcd`
will show up on your console, which may or may not be what you want.  You can control this by redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` in the child process.

Comment: similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123439/python-how-to-run-process-in-detached-mode) which uses `multiprocessing` and `os.fork()`

Answer (score -1):

Posting this if for no other reason than finding it next time I google the same question:

```
 if os.fork() == 0:
    os.close(0)
    os.close(1)
    os.close(2)
    subprocess.Popen(('etcd'),close_fds=True)
    sys.exit(0)
```

Popen close_fds closes the file descriptors other than 0,1,2, so the code closes them explicitly.