# return value from one python script to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

I have two files: script1.py and script2.py. I need to invoke script2.py from script1.py and return the value from script2.py back to script1.py. But the catch is script1.py actually runs script2.py through os.

script1.py:

```
import os
print(os.system("script2.py 34"))
```

script2.py

```
import sys
def main():
    x="Hello World"+str(sys.argv[1])
    return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x= main()
```

As you can see, I am able to get the value into script2, but not back to script1. How can I do that? NOTE: script2.py HAS to be called as if its a commandline execution. Thats why I am using os.

Comment: What should be returned from `script2.py`? Is return code sufficient?

Comment: I want the value x to be returned. In this case script2 should return "Hello World 34"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, if I understand you correctly you want to:

- pass an argument to another script
- retrieve an output from another script to original caller

I'll recommend using subprocess module. Easiest way would be to use [check_output()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function.

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

Sample solution:

script1.py

```
import sys
import subprocess
s2_out = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "script2.py", "34"])
print s2_out
```

script2.py:

```
import sys
def main(arg):
    print("Hello World"+arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get an TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable error. Is it because of the python version? I am using 3.4

Comment: @user567 sorry, you have to pass 34 as string. I'll edit an answer.

Comment: @Łukasz Rogalski, how can I validate the s2_out if  print(1) in script2.py?

Answer (score 12):

The recommended way to return a value from one python "script" to another is to import the script as a Python module and call the functions directly:

```
import another_module

value = another_module.get_value(34)
```

where `another_module.py` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def get_value(*args):
    return "Hello World " + ":".join(map(str, args))

def main(argv):
    print(get_value(*argv[1:]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    main(sys.argv)
```

You could both import `another_module` and run it as a script from the command-line. If you don't need to run it as a command-line script then you could remove `main()` function and `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.

See also, [Call python script with input with in a python script using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30165768/4279).