Using a variable between two files
I have been trying multiple ways to try and get a variable from file#1 to file#2 but every time I import file#1 to file#2 it seems like file#2 fails to work.
I think this is due to file#2 being run in a subprocess in file#1 but I'm not too sure. Is there a way for me to import the variable without this happening or should I do a main file and run the other 2 files from there?
testaction is the variable I am trying to use in the other file.
Ex:
File#1
def listen_for_command():
    global testaction
    global keyword_detected
    while keyword_detected:
        try:
            if "weather in" in cortana_input:
                testaction = "weather"
                city_text = cortana_input.split("weather in", 1)[1].strip()
                print(f"Fetching weather for {city_text}")
                #weather based on city
                weather_info = get_weather_data(city_text)
                print(weather_info)
                engine.say(weather_info)
                engine.runAndWait()

File#2
#import file#1 or from file#1 import testaction causes file#2 to not run
def listen_for_input():
    global action, next_action, animation_active
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter action: ").strip()
        #I want user_input = testaction

This is how I have the files set up running in File#2
# Start the keyword listener in a separate thread
keyword_thread = threading.Thread(target=listen_for_keyword, daemon=True)
keyword_thread.start()

# Wait for the keyword detection before starting the animation script
while not keyword_detected:
    time.sleep(1)

animation_thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: subprocess.run(["python", "animation.py"]))
animation_thread.start()
listen_for_command()
# Once the keyword is detected, start the animation script


Mixing threading and multiprocessing is complex and confusing. The subprocess does indeed inhibit the parent process from inspecting anything about the internal state of the subprocess. You don't see the internal variables of ls or cat if you run them in subprocesses, either.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982820/return-a-variable-value-from-a-subprocess-in-python shows how to communicate back to the parent process but the proper answer is probably to not use a subprocess at all.

You seem to use plain functions. Try creating a class in one file you want the variable to be extracted then create a __init__ function to store the var, then create another function to get the variable you have stored.
ex code file 2:
class var_record:
    def __init__(self,clock):#clock is just var
               self.clock = clock
               # it helps to access the clock in       
               # other sub functions 

    def get_clock(self):# no additional vars
              return self.clock
              # that's it for file 2

ex code file1:
""""
import the py file where we have the var stored.    note: the class file should be in the same folder as the code to import file

from (class file name)import (classname)

"""
# real code file 1 
from clocker import var_tecord as v
a = v(1000)
print(a.get_clock)

output:
1000


please find the error
