# Running script via subprocess.Popen with return value

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a simple script which is having the structure of:

```
if __name__ =='main':
    #do some logic
    #print to console the result
```

Now, I ran the script via the code using `subprocess.Popen()` method like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
  ["python", path_of_script_to_run] + arguments_list, 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

My question is how can I return a value from the running script to the calling script using return value, or other method.

I cannot use return under the context of `if __name__ =='main':`
So does it mean I cannot pass a return value to be assigned in the calling script to the `p` variable?
I'm also want to try avoiding parsing the prints of the script run to the console..

Comment: list + list in python is a list concatenated

Comment: You can use `exit` to set the return code. Suppose for instance that you want to return 2, just do `exit(2)`.

Comment: I want to pass something like a tuple of integers for example (1,5)

Comment: The best way to do this is to import the script to be run and call a method that returns the required data. Please see the answer by JF Sebastian http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664263/return-value-from-one-python-script-to-another

Comment: Its common to write the data to `stdout` and have the parent script parse it. But if the script is also pumping out other stuff that makes it hard to parse, you've got a problem. Perhaps that child script should have a "terse mode" flag that tells it to stop being chatty and just return an easily parsed result.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to retrieve output of your script. And [`returncode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) to get the exit code.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
  ["python", path_of_script_to_run] + arguments_list, 
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
  stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

(stdoutdata, stderrdata) = p.communicate()
exit_code = p.returncode
```

For your other script to return an exit code, you should use [`sys.exit(code)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit).

```
import sys
if __name__ =='main':
    try:
        # do stuff
        sys.exit(0)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: but how do I pass the return code from the context of the running script, trying to write return [something], cannot work as you get syntax error- 'return' out side of function

Comment: Use [`sys.exit(code)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) in your script

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the output in the calling script using  [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
from subprocess import check_output
result = check_output(args).decode()
```

To also capture standard error in the result, use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`.

Comment: but how do I pass the return code from the context of the running script, trying to write return [something], cannot work as you get syntax error- 'return' out side of function

Comment: @JavaSa just `print` it?

Comment: thats exactly what I wanted to avoid, prints and parsing the prints are more weak that returning a value

Comment: But I guess I can't

Comment: @JavaSa, it's more that you aren't explaining what you mean by "returning" very clearly. If you want the Python interpreter to exit with that status that's easy, but it's not obvious that that's what you're asking for.

Comment: I want to be able to pass return value like you have  a simple function
`def foo():
   return (1,4)`
for example,
and in the caller side i get the values like:
`x,y = subprocess(.....)`
Where x =1 and y =4