# Get stdout output as list of dictionary instead of string

Tags: python, json, subprocess, stdout, httpresponse

I'm running a python script with subprocess, which will in turn run another test.py script and get some output.

test.py  , does some parsing and outputs the list of dictionaries.

```
  data = [{'a': 12, 'name':'abc'}, {'a': 16, 'name':xyz}, {'a': 17, 'name': lmn}]

  def func1:
  cmd = 'python {}{}{} {} {}'.format(settings.BASE_DIR,'test.py',arg1,arg2)
  p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
  out, err = p.communicate()
  return(p.returncode,err, out)

  def funct2(request):
    if request.GET:
        statuscode,err,resp = func1(arg1,arg2)       
        if not err and statuscode == 0:
             return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'resp':resp,'status_code':statuscode,'err':err}),content_type="application/json")
```

So that i can handle this data  in my javascript to get json object. 
As of now in my .js file its coming has string even after JSON.parse(resp)

My question is how do i send output of test.py as a list only and handle it further to get a JSON object in my javascript as shown below.

Comment: use pickle. refer this https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Comment: @Pradam can you be more specific on where to i use pickle here before writing it to sys.stdout.write(str(data)) ? or later

Comment: is data a string object?

Comment: @Rakesh No data is a list of dict. 
data = [{'a': 12, 'name':'abc'}, {'a': 16, 'name':xyz}, {'a': 17, 'name': lmn}].
If i try to return data as it is it throws error.

Comment: @Rachel what error is it throwing..?

Comment: @Pradam sorry it does not throw any error but  out, err = p.communicate()
out is empty

Comment: @Rachel if you put more code it will be more useful so can able to rectify what's happening.

Comment: @Pradam i have edited the question and added some code hope it helps

Comment: @Rachel Hope it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664263/return-value-from-one-python-script-to-another

Comment: @Pradam it is not much of use. Is it possible to change subprocess.popen() 
output to list