# Receive return data from subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm spawning a process from a script using `subprocess`. My `subprocess` takes a JSON input and performs some operations and should return some real time data to the main process. How can I do this from `subprocess`?
I'm trying something like this. But it is throwing an error.

Following is may main process "main.py"

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['python','handler.py'],
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p.communicate(JSONEncoder().encode(data))
while True:
     out = process.stdout.read(1)
     if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
     if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Below is my `subprocess` "handler.py"

```
if __name__ == '__main__' :

   command = json.load(sys.stdin)
   os.environ["PYTHONPATH"] = "../../"

   if command["cmd"] == "archive" :
      print "command recieved:",command["cmd"]
      file_ids, count = archive(command["files"])
      sys.stdout.write(JSONEncoder().encode(file_ids))
```

But it throws an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./core/main.py", line 46, in <module>
  out = p.stdout.read(1)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Am I doing something wrong here??

Comment: Where does `process` come from? You create `p` with `subprocessPopen`.

Answer (score 2):

`communicate` reads all the output from a subprocess and closes it. If you want to be able to read from the process after writing, you have to use something other than `communicate`, such as `p.stdin.write`. Alternatively, just use the output of `communicate`; it should have what you want https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects.

Answer (score 2):

`Popen.communicate()` does not return until the process is dead and it returns all the output. You can't read subprocess' stdout after it. Look at the top of [the `.communicate()` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. ***Read data*** from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. ***Wait for process to terminate.***<sub>emphasis is mine</sub>

If you want to send data and then read the output line by line as text while the child process is still running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import json
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, universal_newline=True) as process:
    with process.stdin as pipe:
        pipe.write(json.dumps(data))
    for line in process.stdout:
        print(line, end='')
        process(line)
```

If you need code for older python versions or you have buffering issues, see [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2715847/4279).

If all you want is to pass data to the child process and to print the output to terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
import json
import subprocess

subprocess.run(command, input=json.dumps(data).encode())
```

If your actual child process is a Python script then consider importing it as a module and running the corresponding functions instead, see [Call python script with input with in a python script using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279).