# Get output and Return code from external shell command in python

Tags: python, windows, console, subprocess

Suppose I run a command `cmd="start python Testscript.py"` using subprocess in python.

```
subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

> 1. Is there any way to get the output of the new command console ?
> 2. Is there any way to get the return code from the TestScript.py into the calling python function.

Comment: 1- Is there a reason, not to run the `python` executable directly without the shell and the `start` command? 2- Can you modify `Testscript.py`, to [import it instead of running it as a subprocess](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)?

Comment: As I need to show the result of the running script in a new console window.so i was curious about the possibilities