# Sending arguments to a program that is already open in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, communication, popen

What I am trying to do is better explained here: [Sending to the stdin of a program in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560427/sending-to-the-stdin-of-a-program-in-python3)

I am trying to send arguments to a program while it is open e.g:

rec.py

```
import sys
import time

while True:
   print(sys.argv)
   time.sleep(1)
```

send.py

```
import subprocess

program = Popen(['python.exe', 'rec.py', 'testArg'])
a = input('input: ')
a.communicate(b)
```

I want to be able to run send.py and type in my input. Say my input was 'cat', I would want the output to look like this when I run send.py

```
['rec.py', 'testArg']
['rec.py', 'testArg']
['rec.py', 'testArg']
cat <------- My input
['rec.py', 'testArg', 'cat']
['rec.py', 'testArg', 'cat']
['rec.py', 'testArg', 'cat']
['rec.py', 'testArg', 'cat']
```

ect..

Am I using the subprocess.Popen.communicate() incorrectly or is it something else?

Please help!

-Thanks

Comment: `a` is a `str` in your case (the type returned by `input()` function). It has no `.communicate()` attribute. Don't type the code from memory. Create a minimal but complete code example and post the code that you actually have tried to run [as is]. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the command-line arguments  after the program has started i.e., `sys.argv` can be changed only from the inside (normally) of the process itself.

`Popen.communicate(input=data)` can send `data` to the child process via its standard input (if you pass `stdin=PIPE` to `Popen()`). `.communicate()` waits for the process to exit before returning and therefore it can be used to send all the input at once.

To send the input incrementally, use `process.stdin` directly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen([sys.executable, 'child.py'], 
           stdin=PIPE, # redirect process' stdin
           bufsize=1, # line-buffered
           universal_newlines=True # text mode
           ) as process:
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(.5)
        print(i, file=process.stdin, flush=True)
```

where `child.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys

for line in sys.stdin: # read from the standard input line-by-line
    i = int(line)
    print(i * i) # square
```

A better option is to import the module and use its functions instead. See [Call python script with input with in a python script using subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)

Comment: When i run the first program i get the error,     print(i, file=process.stdin, flush=True)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Comment: @Nic: the code works as is (I've tested it). If it doesn't work for you then create a new (separate) question where you should mention the exact Python version, your OS, how do you run the script? (in IDE/console, what is the current directory? (do you see `child.py` in there?), the exact filenames that you use, etc), and the complete traceback. Make sure that you've copied the code exactly as it is in the answer.

Comment: I have made a knew question addressing what I want to do more in detail. Its here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560427/sending-to-the-stdin-of-a-program-in-python3

Comment: @Nic I don't see how it reproduces OSError.

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way interprocess-communication works. You are mixing command line arguments with the standard input pipe.

This will work:

#### rec.py:

```
import sys
import time
arguments = list(sys.argv)

while True:
    print(arguments)
    arguments.append(next(sys.stdin))
```

#### send.py

```
import subprocess
program = subprocess.Popen(['python.exe', 'rec.py', 'testArg'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
a = input('input: ')
program.stdin.write(a + '\n')
```

Comment: It won't work due to the buffering. Try: `print(a, file=program.stdin, flush=True)` instead (pass `universal_newlines=True`, to enable the text mode)

Comment: When I run the code, I get the error: print(a, file=program.stdin, flush=True)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' (thats with @J.F.Sebastian print code), with  the sefault, I also get the error program.stdin.write(a + '\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @Nic: pass `universal_newlines=True` as it said explicitly in my comment.

Comment: Could you rust write your response as an answer @J.F.Sebastian It would be much more helpful if you could do that