# Generator from function prints

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, subprocess, generator

At the moment I have a little `flask` project that calls another python file. I'm fully aware that this way is kinda awful, and so, I want to swap it for a function call while maintaining **the prints getting yelded to the website**.

```
def get_Checks():
    root = request.url_root

    def func():
        yield ("Inicio <br>")
        with subprocess.Popen(r"python somefile.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1,
                              universal_newlines=True) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                yield (line + "<br>")

    return Response(func())
```

I've tryed to replace the file call with the function directly but it just prints it to the console.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all the printing you want to grab is done within the same module, You can monkey-patch the `print` function of the other module. In the example below, I use a context manager to revert the original print function after the grabbing is done.

This is `mod1`, the module with the misbehaving function.

```
def bogus_function():
    print('Hello World!')
    print('Line 2')
```

This is `mod2`, the module using `mod1.bogus_function()`

```
import io
import functools
import contextlib

import mod1

@contextlib.contextmanager
def grab_stdout(module, fd):
    def monkey_print(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['file'] = fd
        print(*args, **kwargs)

    setattr(module, 'print', monkey_print)
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        setattr(module, 'print', print)

def line_generator():
    fd = io.StringIO()
    with grab_stdout(mod1, fd):
        mod1.bogus_function()
    fd.seek(0)

    for line in fd:
        yield line.rstrip('\r\n') + '<br>'

for t in enumerate(line_generator()):
    print('line %d: %r' % t)
```

The `grab_stdout()` context manager redirects print calls of `module` to the file-like object `fd`. In the function `line_generator()`, `grab_stdout()` is used to store the print output of `bogus_function` in the `StringIO` object `fd`. The rest should be self-explanatory.

If you don't know exactly whether print is called in other modules in the call tree of the function in question, you can modify `grab_stdout` as follows:

```
import builtins
print_orig = builtins.print

@contextlib.contextmanager
def grab_stdout_global(fd):
    def monkey_print(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['file'] = fd
        print_orig(*args, **kwargs)

    builtins.print = monkey_print
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        builtins.print = print_orig
```

Comment: Damm, that's more complex than what I anticipated, but let me give it a try.

Comment: It's working but it prints the newline(\n) at the end of every line, any way of getting rid of it. (aside from replace at the end)

Comment: @EndermanAPM Alright, I only added the print loop with enumerate to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: @EndermanAPM To remove newlines, just use `line.rstrip('\r\n')`

Comment: It's alright, without the enumerate it's working even better than before :) The old method had some problems with the encoding of some characters :)

Comment: With my test file is working fine but when I tried to use it with the actual "prod" file it prints it's prints but not the prints that are generated from the functions that the file calls. In your example it would be like bogus_function calling another function.

Comment: grab_stdout_global replaces grab_stdout?

Comment: Indeed. Note that there is no `module` argument anymore.

Comment: I see.. So, if its global, when and how can I end the stdout grab?

Comment: That's why I put the replacement of the print function in a context manager. The print function is only replaced inside the `with` block (where `mod1.bogus_function()` is called). In the next line `fd.seek(0)`, the original print function is already restored, even if an exception is thrown inside the `with` block. If your application is multithreaded, you have of course a chance that the print output of unrelated function calls is captures as well. But that is the case will all solutions that replace print or stdout. There are no thread-local module attributes AFAIK.

Comment: Oh :( The global thingy is not working for me, it just don't print anything anywhere. Could the python native yield and the flask one be conflicting?

Comment: Well, I won't help you debugging. It should work based on the assumption that `module.__builtins__` is the very same dictionary as `builtins.__dict__` (as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html)). I checked that with on my machine with Python 3.5.2. You could, for example add the line `assert print is builtins.print` in some locations that are supposed to be executed in the `with` block.

Comment: `yield` is not a builtin like `print`, but a keyword. The workings of yield can not be altered.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to temporarily change `sys.stdout` to a file-like object, call the function, then restore `sys.stdout`. The output will be available in the file-like object.

Here is a working Flask app that demonstrates the method:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import somefile

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    def func():
        yield ("Inicio <br>")

        try:
            _stdout = sys.stdout
            sys.stdout = output = StringIO()
            somefile.main()
            output.seek(0)
            for line in output:
                sys.stdout = _stdout
                yield '{}<br>'.format(line.rstrip())
                sys.stdout = output
        finally:
            sys.stdout.close()    # close the StringIO object
            sys.stdout = _stdout  # restore sys.stdout

    return Response(func())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here a [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=pipe#io.StringIO) object is used to collect the standard output produced by the function, and then the lines are yielded from that object. The `finally` ensures that the original `sys.stdout` is restored afterwards. There is some additional complexity around the `yield` statement because `yield` returns control to the calling code for which stdout must be restored in case the caller also wants to print to stdout.

It's assumed that the function in `somefile.py` is the "main" function, and that invocation of it is guarded by a `if __name__ == '__main__':` test, something like this:

```
def main():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is not working for me :S It just dones't print anything anywhere.

Comment: @EndermanAPM: possibly you are trying this out in the interactive interpreter? If that is the case then fooling about with `stdout` will also affect your interpreter's `stdout`. This code is intended to be executed as a script, not interactively. It definitely works in a Flask app - see updated answer.

Comment: @EndermanAPM: BTW, is there a reason that you can not simply update the function in `somefile.py` to have it yield those lines rather than print them? Then you could just call it as a generator.

Comment: No, I'm not running from the interactive interpreter and I suppose i could rewrite `somefile.py`.

Comment: Does the full Flask app that I added to my answer work? (It does for me)

Comment: It does not on my app,  later I'll try it on its own

Comment: @EndermanAPM: don't confuse `return` and `print` statements. If you want to [call a function instead of running a module as a script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279) then you should use `return` (or `yield`), not `print`. If you have to use stdout as a way to return a value from a function then you could use [`contextlib.stdout_redirect()` context manager](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22434262/4279) (make sure to add `flush=True` to your `print` statements or unbuffer `sys.stdout`, to get values in time).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I admit that my answer may lack a reference to `contextlib.stdout_redirect()` (which I managed to overlook at that time). But could you please tell me how downvoting it and promoting your own answer to a related question improves the situation?