# How could I connect a program with interface in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to use tkinter to set a interface for my another program, but I do not know what is my next step.

I do not know how to connect each other.

I do not have that concept.

This is the code of trying to be a interface:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -O
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
subprocess.call('/Users/Tsu-
AngChou/MasterProject/Practice/try_test/TEST5.py')

root = Tk(className ="Documents retriever")
svalue = StringVar() # defines the widget state as string
w = Entry(root,textvariable=svalue) # adds a textarea widget
w.pack()
def act():
    print ("you entered")
    print ('%s' % svalue.get())
foo = Button(root,text="Retrieve", command=act)
foo.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This is the code of my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join


mypath = "/Users/Tsu-AngChou/MasterProject/Practice/try_test/"
files = listdir(mypath)
storage = {}
translator = str.maketrans("","",string.punctuation)
for f in files:
  fullpath = join(mypath, f)
  if f == '.DS_Store':
            os.remove(f)
  elif isfile(fullpath):

    print(f)
    for html_cont in range(1):
        response = open(f,'r',encoding='utf-8')
        html_cont = response.read()
        soup = bs(html_cont, 'html.parser')
        regular_string = soup.get_text()
        new_string = regular_string.translate(translator).split()
        new_list = [item[:14] for item in new_string]
        a = dict.fromkeys(new_list, f)
        b = a
        storage.update(a)
        print(a)
        storage.append(new_list)

        wordfreq = []
        for w in new_list:
            wordfreq.append(new_list.count(w))
        print("Frequency:\n" ,list(zip(b,wordfreq)))
```

I want to use the value(a) and value(list(zip(b,wordfreq))
How could I give the Button value?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do?

Comment: I need a interface that I can input the keyword, then it will show me which file has that word.

Comment: What is the difficulty you're having about that there? What is the variable name for keyword?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076185/call-python-script-with-input-with-in-a-python-script-using-subprocess) might help.

Comment: put code in secon file in function and `import` it To file with gui

Answer (score 0):

If you want to processes to 'talk' to each other, you can use the subprocesses module in the Python Standard Library.

Answer (score 0):

You have some files.py that have functions and classes.

Then, you have an ifmain in each files to test librairies you built. Because this is what you're doing at your own level.

You use, then, a main file to link all of this together. And in your main file you can add an optional argument that takes your program output, and... well. I guess you know what to do next. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put code in script inside function and add `if __name__ == "__main__"` to the end

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def my_function(mypath = "/Users/Tsu-AngChou/MasterProject/Practice/try_test/"):
    files = listdir(mypath)
    storage = {}
    translator = str.maketrans("","",string.punctuation)
    for f in files:
      fullpath = join(mypath, f)
      if f == '.DS_Store':
                os.remove(f)
      elif isfile(fullpath):

        print(f)
        for html_cont in range(1):
            response = open(f,'r',encoding='utf-8')
            html_cont = response.read()
            soup = bs(html_cont, 'html.parser')
            regular_string = soup.get_text()
            new_string = regular_string.translate(translator).split()
            new_list = [item[:14] for item in new_string]
            a = dict.fromkeys(new_list, f)
            b = a
            storage.update(a)
            print(a)
            storage.append(new_list)

            wordfreq = []
            for w in new_list:
                wordfreq.append(new_list.count(w))
            print("Frequency:\n" ,list(zip(b,wordfreq)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   my_function()
```

So it will still work as standalone script but now you can `import` it in second file and execute. I execut it in `act()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -O

from tkinter import *
from my_scipt import my_function

def act():
    print("you entered")
    print(svalue.get())
    my_function()

root = Tk()
svalue = StringVar()
w = Entry(root, textvariable=svalue)
w.pack()
foo = Button(root, text="Retrieve", command=act)
foo.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: you can execute `my_function` with parameter

```
my_function("/path/to/different/folder")
```

but you can create function with more arguments and execute

```
my_function("/path/", a, b)
```

---

If you need some values from this function then use in function

```
return value1, value2
```

and then you can use it as

```
val1, val2 = my_function("/path/", a, b)
```