# Execute IPython notebook cell from python script

Tags: python, ipython

In the IPython notebook, you can execute an outside script, say `test.py`, using the run magic:

```
%run test.py
```

Is there a way to do the opposite, i.e. given an IPython notebook, accessing and then running a particular cell inside it from a python script?

Comment: IPython has a format like xml. You can parse it and run the cell you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file with extention "ipynb" of Jupyter (or IPython) is a JSON file. And the cells are under the name "cells" ["cells"]. Then you choose the number of the cell [0] and to get the source choose "source" ["source"]. In return you get an array with one element so you need to get the first element [0].

```
>>> import json
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> with open('so1.ipynb', 'r') as content_file:
...     content = content_file.read()
... 
>>> data=json.loads(content)
>>> data["cells"][0]["source"][0]
'1+1'
>>> eval(data["cells"][0]["source"][0])
2
>>> data["cells"][1]["source"][0]
'2+2'
>>> eval(data["cells"][1]["source"][0])
4
```

**EDIT:**

To run other python scripts in cells that have %run:

```
os.system(data["cells"][2]["source"][0].replace("%run ",""))
```

Or replace it with the following if you have -i option:

```
execfile(data["cells"][2]["source"][0].replace("%run -i ",""))
```

See [Run a python script from another python script, passing in args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781851/run-a-python-script-from-another-python-script-passing-in-args) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything I could do if say the cell had a jupyter/ipython specific magic in it, such as %run?

Comment: Hii, I have a notebook which plots the graph, and when I execute that cell using this method I am not getting any output. Is there any work around?

Comment: Things to check: is there plt.show() at the end, is a compatible matplotlib backend used. Interactive backend used in Jupyter is not compatible with plain python.