# How to execute file in Python with arguments using import?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I read that you can execute a file using `import` like this
**file.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import file2
```

**file2.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello World!"
```

And **file.py** will print `Hello World`. How would I execute this file with arguments, using `import`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309456/how-to-call-a-function-from-another-file-in-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781960/391161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program arguments are available in `sys.argv` and can be used by any module. You could change file2.py to

```
import sys
print "Here are my arguments", sys.argv
```

You can use the [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module for more complex parsing.

Comment: He doesn't want the arguments to be received from terminal. He wants to send them through the "import" statement.

Comment: @Bharel OP never stated where the arguments come from or how they are consumed in *file2.py*. He certainly did not say they were not standard program arguments.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm sorry, apparently my instructions weren't clear enough. But I want to **execute** a file using import, if possible.

Comment: @bjskistad - what do you mean by "execute"? Importing causes the module to be executed. Its `__name__` is `file2` instead of `__main__` but otherwise it is pretty much the same as executing it directly from the command line.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few lines to *file2.py* to show how you want to use the arguments and add some detail about where these arguments come from - is it from the command line? Is *file1.py* generating them?

Answer (score 1):

Import is not meant for execution of scripts. It is used in order to fetch or "import" functions, classes and attributes it contains.

If you wish to execute the script using a different interpreter, and give it arguments, you should use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).

---

In Python 2 you may use [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) if you need the programs output.

Comment: Yes and no. If you install a package, modules aren't in the system `PATH` and its common to include helper scripts in the `PATH` to run them. Also, this import technique lets you fiddle with the system environment before the target script is run.

Comment: I'm using 2.7, is there any way to do this in 2.7? Or do I need to upgrade to 3.x?

Comment: @bjskistad added for Python 2.